# Why don't LLVM passes optimize floating point instructions?

Tags: floating-point, llvm, compiler-optimization

See above. I wrote to sample functions:

`source.ll:`

```
define i32 @bleh(i32 %x) {
entry:
  %addtmp = add i32 %x, %x
  %addtmp1 = add i32 %addtmp, %x
  %addtmp2 = add i32 %addtmp1, %x
  %addtmp3 = add i32 %addtmp2, %x
  %addtmp4 = add i32 %addtmp3, 1
  %addtmp5 = add i32 %addtmp4, 2
  %addtmp6 = add i32 %addtmp5, 3
  %multmp = mul i32 %x, 3
  %addtmp7 = add i32 %addtmp6, %multmp
  ret i32 %addtmp7
}
```

`source-fp.ll:`

```
define double @bleh(double %x) {
entry:
  %addtmp = fadd double %x, %x
  %addtmp1 = fadd double %addtmp, %x
  %addtmp2 = fadd double %addtmp1, %x
  %addtmp3 = fadd double %addtmp2, %x
  %addtmp4 = fadd double %addtmp3, 1.000000e+00
  %addtmp5 = fadd double %addtmp4, 2.000000e+00
  %addtmp6 = fadd double %addtmp5, 3.000000e+00
  %multmp = fmul double %x, 3.000000e+00
  %addtmp7 = fadd double %addtmp6, %multmp
  ret double %addtmp7
}
```

Why is it that when I optimize both functions using

`opt -O3 source[-fp].ll -o opt.source[-fp].ll -S`

that the `i32` one gets optimized but the `double` one doesn't? I expected the `fadd` to get combined to a single `fmul`. Instead it looks exactly the same.

Is it due to the flags being set differently? I am aware of certain optimizations that are possible for `i32` that are not doable for `double`. But the absence of simple constant folding is beyond my understanding.

I am using LLVM 3.1.

Comment: Highly relevant, though I'm not sure if it's a duplicate: [Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6430448/395760)

Comment: @delan This, like a ton of similar floating-point questions, is indeed a duplicate of that. The answer is the same even if the details of the question vary. Any good answer to this question would point out the non-associativity of floating-point arithmetic and mention -ffast-math, just like the accepted answer of that question does.

Comment: Thank you both. An answer of the linked question brought up http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and emphasizes its section on ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not quite true to say that *no* optimization is possible.  I'll go through the first few lines to show where transformations are and are not allowed:

```
  %addtmp = fadd double %x, %x
```

This first line could safely be transformed to `fmul double %x 2.0e+0`, but that's not actually an optimization on most architectures (`fadd` is generally as fast or faster than `fmul`, and doesn't require producing the constant `2.0`).  Note that barring overflow, this operation is exact (like all scaling by powers of two).

```
  %addtmp1 = fadd double %addtmp, %x
```

This line could be transformed to `fmul double %x 3.0e+0`.  Why is this a legal transformation?  Because the computation that produced `%addtmp` was exact, so only a single rounding is been incurred whether this is computed as `x * 3` or `x + x + x`.  Because these are IEEE-754 basic operations and therefore correctly rounded, the result is the same either way.  What about overflow?  Neither may overflow unless the other does as well.

```
  %addtmp2 = fadd double %addtmp1, %x
```

This is the first line that cannot be legally transformed into constant * x.  `4 * x` would compute exactly, without any rounding, whereas `x + x + x + x` incurs two roundings: `x + x + x` is rounded once, then adding `x` may round a second time.

```
  %addtmp3 = fadd double %addtmp2, %x
```

Ditto here; `5 * x` would incur one rounding; `x + x + x + x + x` incurs three.

The only line that might be beneficially transformed would be replacing `x + x + x` with `3 * x`.  However, the subexpression `x + x` is already present elsewhere, so an optimizer easily could choose not to employ this transform (since it can take advantage of the existing partial result if it does not).

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. So doing a `fmul double %x 2.0e+0` and constant propagating the result is still slower than repeating `fadd`s? Or am I missing rounding issues?

Comment: `2*x` and `x+x` are numerically equivalent; however, on common architectures, `x+x` is no slower than (and sometimes faster than) `2*x`, so there's generally no reason for an optimizer to use `2*x`.

Comment: But calculating `x+x` twice (and then adding `x`) seems slower than doing something like `%y1 = fadd double %x, %x`, `%y2 = fadd double %y1, %y1`, `%res = fadd double %y2, %x`. I didn't want to emphasize `fmul` which was probably misleading.