# How raise to power works? Is it worth to use pow(x, 2)?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it more efficient to do multiplication than raise to power 2 in c++?

I am trying to do final detailed optimizations. Will the compiler treat
x*x the same as pow(x,2)? If I remember correctly, multiplication was
better for some reason, but maybe it does not matter in c++11.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on whether the optimizer (or function's implementation possibly) takes care of it. Look at the produced assembly or benchmark it.

Comment: I imagine `x << 1` is what is actually happening.

Comment: `x^2` is _not_ raise to power 2!

Comment: I certainly hope the compiler won't treat `x*x` the same as `x^2` because `^` is XOR not `pow`.

Comment: ah yes sorry, I meant pow instead of ^

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're comparing multiplication with the [`pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) standard library function then yes, multiplication is definitely faster.

Answer (score 6):

I general, you should not worry about pico-optimizations like that unless you have **evidence** that there is a hot-spot (i.e. unless you've profiled your code under realistic scenarios and have identified a particular chunk of code. Also keep in mind that your clever tricks may actually cause performance regressions in new processors where your assumptions will no longer hold.

Algorithmic changes are where you will get the most bang for your computing buck. Focus on that.

Tinkering with multiplications and doing clever bit-hackery... eh not so much bang there* Because the current generation of optimizing compilers is really **quite excellent** at their job. That's not to say they can't be beat. They can, but not easily and probably only by a few people like Agner Fog.

** there are, of course, exceptions.*

Comment: +1 for "They can, but not easily and probably only by a few people like Agner Fog." Ain't that the truth!

Comment: Interestingly enough, the difference between pow() and multiplication actually IS an algorithmic difference. ;)  Consider if the OP asked the same thing with a different example and wording: "pow(x, 8) expresses my intent more clearly than x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x.  Is multiplication faster?"  You might call it a pico-optimization, but going from pow() to multiplication is technically an algorithmic (+ constant) improvement.  (...and compared to naive sequential multiplication, "x2 = x*x; x4 = x2*x2; answer = x4*x4;" is also a handcoded expansion of an algorithmically improved integer power function.)

Comment: @MikeS The difference might be algorithmic conceptually, but I'm pretty sure that the compiler understands what `pow` is and what semantics it has and so can (usually) optimize it fairly well on its own. So unless there's **hard** evidence that it's a hotspot, this sort of thing should be considered a micro-optimization.

Comment: There are still two problems with that:  1.)  Taking that attitude across your codebase means you could have a whole lot of pow()'s that should be replaced by multiplications (plus a hundred similar pervasive issues).  Performance issues are often isolated to a "few hotspots," but only when the program was coded in a habitually efficient manner to begin with.  Writing everything from a "performance last" viewpoint means that instead of a few hotspots, your program might be consistently slow everywhere (more common as people increasingly abuse/misapply the "premature optimization" maxim).

Comment: 2.)  Questions like this are important, because they aren't isolated to overanalyzing some highly specific code block.  Instead, they're idiomatic questions that allow people to develop the skills to habitually code things efficiently on a consistent basis.  Developing good habits at the nuts and bolts level can save a ton of profiling time, because the amount of effort it takes to isolate hot spots (let alone correct pervasive sluggishness) far exceeds the amount of effort it takes to write basic "building block" code efficiently the first time (once you've learned how).

Comment: I don't disagree with you; as a matter of fact, I think we agree conceptually but approach the issue from slightly different angles. I certainly think that one should try to write efficient code to begin with, and that means learning what does and doesn't make a difference in *that* context. But that's quite different from micro-optimizing as you go.

Comment: Also beware blind faith in compilers: Even ten years ago, most people assumed compilers performed optimizations on a scale they still don't today. (At the micro-optimization level, instruction scheduling still benefits from reordering source code lines!) pow() is rarely replaced with integer intrinsics: Usually the full int->float->pow->int is done, and pow can't be optimized because fp math is not associative. Quick test: With GCC 4.8, pow(i, 2) is as fast as i*i, but pow(i, 4) is 115 times slower than i*i*i*i. With Clang 3.3, it's 337 times slower, since it optimizes the multiplies better.

Comment: Just saw your comment: Micro-optimizing as you go is a brutally slow/unproductive way to code, especially if you get carried away and write unreadable bit-twiddling code (which probably won't help), or if you spend a lot of time reordering instructions to aid the scheduler, etc. It's never a good idea to write unreadable "optimizations" before profiling, but if you're deciding between two equally legible versions of idiomatic code spread across the codebase, investing early in the "habitual learning process" is probably wise...even if it means micro-optimization slog the first time around.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to performance, always make measurements to back up your assumptions. Never trust theory unless you have a benchmark that proves that theory right.

Also, keep in mind that `x ^ 2` does *not* yield the square of 2 in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    std::cout << (x ^ 2); // Prints 6
}
```

[*Live example*](http://ideone.com/InLQ8L).

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of pow() typically involves logarithms, multiplication and expononentiaton, so it will DEFINITELY take longer than a simple multiplication. Most modern high end processors can do multiplication in a couple of clockcycles for integer values, and a dozen or so cycles for floating point multiply. exponentiation is either done as a complex (microcoded) instructions that takes a few dozen or more cycles, or as a series of multiplication and additions (typically with alternating positive and negative numbers, but not certainly). Exponentiation is a similar process.

On lower range processors (e.g. ARM or older x86 processors), the results are even worse. Hundreds of cycles in one floating point operation, or in some processors, even floating point calculations are a number of integer operations that perform the same steps as the float instructions on more advanced processors, so the time taken for `pow()` could be thousands of cycles, compared to a dozen or so for a multiplication.

Whichever choice is used, the whole calculation will be significantly longer than a simple multiplication.

The `pow()` function is useful when the exponent is either large, or not an integer. Even for relatively large exponents, you can do the calculation by squaring or cubing multiple times, and it will be faster than `pow()`.

Of course, sometimes the compiler may be able to figure out what you want to do, and do it as a sequence of multiplications as a optimization. But I wouldn't rely on that.

Finally, as ALWAYS, for performance questions: If it's really important to your code, then measure it - your compiler may be smarter than you thin. If performance isn't important, then perform the calculation that is the makes the code most readable.

Answer (score 1):

`pow` is a library function, not an operator. Unless the compiler is able to optimize out the call (which it legitimately do by taking advantage of its knowledge of the behavior of the standard library functions), calling `pow()` will impose the overhead of a function call and of all the extra stuff the `pow()` function has to do.

The second argument to `pow()` doesn't have to be an integer; for example `pow(x, 1.0/3.0)` will give you an approximation of the cube root of `x`. That's going to require some fairly sophisticated computations. It might fall back to repeated multiplication if the second argument is a small integral value, but then it has to check for that at run time.

If the number you want to square is an integer, `pow` will involve converting it to `double`, then converting the result back to an integer type, which is relatively expensive and could cause subtle rounding errors.

Using `x * x` is very likely to be faster and more reliable than `pow(x, 2)`, and it's simpler. (In most contexts, simplicity and reliability are more important considerations than speed.)

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ does not have a native "power" operator. `^` is the bitwise exclusive or (xor). Thus said, the `pow` function is probably what you are looking for.

Actually, for squaring an integer number, `x*x` is the most immediate way, and some compiler might optimize it to machine operation if available.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the following link
[Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa)

pow(x,2) will most likely be converted to x*x.  However, higher powers such as pow(x,4) may not be done as optimally as possible.  For example pow(x,4) could be done in 3 multiplications x*x*x*x or in two (x*x)*(x*x) depending on how strict you require the floating point definition to be (by default I think it will use 3 multiplications.

It would be interesting to see what for example pow(x*x,2) produces with and without -ffast-math.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into boost.math's pow function template. it takes the exponent as template parameter and automatically calculate, for example, pow<4>(x) as (x*x)*(x*x).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/powers/ct_pow.html