# Basic use of function "contains" in Boost ICL: Are some combinations of interval types and functions not implemented?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-icl

I started to use Boost ICL and I stumbled upon very basic stuff. For example the function `contains` should return true or false depending if a given element is in the interval or not. However that works for `[right,left]_open_intervals` but not for `[open,closed]_inteval` (see example below).

**This seems to be too obvious to be an oversight. I am using the library in the intended way?**

For example (using gcc 4.8 or clang 3.3 and Boost 1.54):

```
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp> //needed to make this MWE work, boost icl should include it internally

#include<boost/icl/right_open_interval.hpp>
#include<boost/icl/closed_interval.hpp>
#include<boost/icl/open_interval.hpp>
int main(){
    boost::icl::right_open_interval<double> roi(6.,7.);
    assert(boost::icl::contains(roi, 6.) == true);  //ok
    assert(boost::icl::contains(roi, 6.) == false); //ok

    boost::icl::closed_interval<double> oi(4.,5.); // or open_interval
    assert(boost::icl::contains( oi, 4.) == false); //error: "candidate template ignored"
    assert(boost::icl::contains( oi, 5.) == false); //error: "candidate template ignored"
}
```

Note: The above are called "static" intervals (because their bound properties are part of the type). Dynamic intervals work as expected.

Comment: After rereading the documentation of Boost ICL, I found this obscure comment in an example: "...You will probably use one kind of static intervals `right_open_intervals` are recommended. ... static closed, left_open and open intervals are implemented for sake of completeness but are of minor practical importance." So for the moment I understand that anything other than `right_open_interval` is not guaranteed to work. I guess I can implement an overload of `contains` but I probably will find another limitation in the future if I insist in using intervals other than `right_open_interval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess it comes down to the relative uselessness of floating point equality testing.

Have you ever tried to do `assert(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)`?

Try it. I'll wait.

In case you already know the answer, it'll be clear why a closed interval is not easy to implement correctly. Backgrounders:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- [Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa/6430525#6430525)
- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Also, if you have two consecutive closed intervals `[a,b][b,c]`. in which interval does `b` belong?

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I was thinking in terms of `open_interval`s for my problem for conceptual reasons. But in reality I shouldn't count on the difference between the different kind of intervals for floating point values and fallback to a single interval type. Still, I would say that the limitation is surprising (although by itself raises your good point). I think at this point we are guessing what was the intention of the library author. (there should be a comma in `[b.c]`)

Comment: Also, the dynamic version of the intervals (the ones described above are called static) works as expected (within the limits of floating point) for example `contains(boost::icl::interval<double>::open(1.,5.),5.) == false`.

Comment: I agree that the feature set for static intervals seems asymmetric w.r.t. the feature set for dynamic intervals. Mmm.

Comment: Using the library a little more I realize that (at least for continuous variables) no effort is made to integrate static(-bounds) intervals with the inteval-containers and dynamic(-bounds) intervals (not even conversion). So at the end the static intervals is like a leftover obscure corner of the library.