# Which boost library should i use to add the intervals as mentioned in the description?

Tags: c++11, boost-icl

I am working on intervals in a c++ program. I want something like below:

I want to add intervals iteratively in a for loop. Assume my first interval is (0, 5). I want to add an interval (3,6) such that the resulting interval set should be (0,3), (3,6). If my third interval added is (4,7), my resulting interval set should be (0,3), (3,4), (4,7).

Any idea what type of interval container should i use from boost library? Any sample programs?

This is what I have tried.....

```
int main()
{
    icl::interval_map<double, std::string> add_map;
    using ival = icl::interval<double>;

    add_map.add({ival::open(1., 2.5), "A1"});
    std::cout<<"adding first interval-----"<<"\n";
    for(auto iter : add_map)
            std::cout << iter.first << ": " << iter.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";

    add_map.add({ival::open(1.5, 5.), "B1"});
    std::cout<<"adding second interval-----"<<"\n";
    for(auto iter : add_map)
        std::cout << iter.first << ": " << iter.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";
    //after adding second interval, i have to get something like (1,1.5]: A1, (1.5,5): B1 
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the following output :
adding first interval-----
(1,2.5): A1,

adding second interval-----
(1,1.5]: A1, (1.5,2.5): A1B1, [2.5,5): B1,

Comment: I am new to interval containers. So, wanted to know which is the best container to use for the above operations.

Comment: IIUC what you want, you simply need to replace `add` with `set`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/function_reference/insertion.html

Answer (score 1):

That is how `interval_map` works: it splits on overlap and creates new intervals. This makes queries for all items given an interval or an element efficient, see [this doc page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) .

What bothers me is that in the text you mention integers, but in the code you use `double`.

Keep in mind that `double` intervals may have problems in the limits. For example `[2, 2.5)` might intersect with `(2.5, 3)` or not, depending on the rounding. See this post  [Basic use of function "contains" in Boost ICL: Are some combinations of interval types and functions not implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540364/basic-use-of-function-contains-in-boost-icl-are-some-combinations-of-interval).

If you just want to store intervals, the data structure I think you need is an [interval set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html).