# Optimization of arithmetic expressions - what is this technique called?

Tags: python, optimization, arithmetic-expressions

A discussion with a friend led to the following realization:

```
>>> import dis
>>> i = lambda n: n*24*60*60
>>> dis.dis(i)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (24)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (60)
             10 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             11 LOAD_CONST               2 (60)
             14 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>> k = lambda n: 24*60*60*n
>>> dis.dis(k)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               4 (86400)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The second example is clearly more efficient simply by reducing the number of instructions.

My question is, is there a name for this optimization, and why doesn't it happen in the first example?

Also, I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of [Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa) ; if it is please explain a bit further as it applies to Python.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This optimization technique is called [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

The reason for constant folding occurring in the latter code but not in the former is that Python has dynamic typing, and while in mathematics a product of real numbers is *commutative* and freely *associative*, it is not so in Python in the general case, because neither do all variables contain real numbers, nor can one know the types beforehand.

---

Multiplication in Python is [left-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) - `24 * 60 * 60 * n` behaves like `(((24 * 60) * 60) * n)`, which in turn implicitly executes like

```
(24).__mul__(60).__mul__(60).__mul__(n)
```

or

```
(n).__rmul_((24).__mul__(60).__mul__(60))
```

whereas `n * 24 * 60 * 60` which is `(((n * 24) * 60) * 60)` *can* behave like

```
n.__mul__(24).__mul__(60).__mul__(60)
```

or

```
(24).__rmul__(n).__mul__(60).__mul__(60)
```

Since we cannot know the behaviour of `n.__mul__` beforehand, we cannot fold a constant in the latter case. Consider this example of a funny class that returns a subclass of `int` that defines `__mul__`/`__rmul__` as returning the sum of the operands instead of product:

```
class MultiplyAsAdd(int):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return MultiplyAsAdd(self + other)
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return MultiplyAsAdd(other + self)
```

Then

```
>>> (lambda n: 24*60*60*n)(MultiplyAsAdd(5))
86405
>>> (lambda n: n*24*60*60)(MultiplyAsAdd(5))
149
```

Clearly it'd be wrong for Python to parenthesize the product as `n*(24*60*60)` in the latter case.