# Can the x86 do FPU operations independently or in parallel?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, fpu, pipelining

My teacher claims that the processor can sometimes do FPU operations in parallel. Like this:

```
float a = 3.14;
float b = 5.12;
float c;
float d = 3.02;
float e = 2.52;
float f;
c = a + b;
f = e + d;
```

So, as I've heard, the 2 add operations above would be executed quicker than:

```
float a = 3.14;
float b = 5.12;
float c;
float d = 3.02;
float e = 2.52;
float f;
c = a + b;
f = c + d;
```

because the processor has to wait until `c` gets computed.

I wanted to verify this, so I wrote a function that does the second thing, and it measures the time by checking the Time Stamp Counter:

```
flds    h # st(7)
flds    g # st(6)
flds    f # st(5)
flds    e # st(4)
flds    d # st(3)
flds    c # st(2)
flds    b # st(1)
flds    a # st(0)
fadd    %st, %st(1) # i = a + b
fmul    %st, %st(2) # j = i * c
fadd    %st, %st(3) # k = j + d
fmul    %st, %st(4) # l = k + e
fadd    %st, %st(5) # m = l + f
fmul    %st, %st(6) # n = m * g
fadd    %st, %st(7) # o = n + h
```

Those are not independent. Now, I am trying to write independent ones. But the problem is, no matter what I actually do, the value is always saved to `ST(0)` (no matter which instruction I use), optionally it can then be popped, but that still means we have to wait until computation.

I looked at the code generated by a compiler (`gcc -S`). It simply doesn't operate like this on `st` registers. For every number, it does:

```
flds number
fstps -some_value(%ebp)
```

And then (for example, for a and b, where `-4(%ebp)` is a, `-8(%ebp)` is b):

```
flds    -4(%ebp)
fadds   -8(%ebp) # i = a + b
fstps   -32(%ebp)
```

So it firstly loads to FPU, and pops back to the normal stack. Then, it pops one value (to `st(0)`), adds to that value, and the result is popped back. So it's still not independent, because we have to wait until `st(0)` gets freed.

Did my teacher say something wrong, or is there a way to make them independent that would give a noticeably different execution time when I measure it?

Comment: Microprocessors these days are capable of [_register renaming_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming), wherein an _architectural_ register name can map to one of many registers in the _physical register file_. So if `st(0)` is written to, then read, then written to again by an independent computation, the hardware will rename `st(0)` invisibly to avoid a WAR (write-after-read) data hazard on the independent computation.

Comment: At any rate, most floating-point mathematics these days is done not on the legacy x87 unit but the vector SSE unit, using either scalar instructions such as `movss xmm0, -somvevalue(%rbp)` and `addss xmm0, xmm1` or their vector cousins `movaps xmm0, -somvevalue(%rbp)` and `addps xmm0, xmm1`. Vector registers can also be renamed, and they are easier to use than the hardware floating-point stack in the x87 unit. In particular they expose parallelism much better.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the style of [PolitiFact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2013/nov/01/principles-politifact-punditfact-and-truth-o-meter/), I would rate your teacher's statement that "the processor can sometimes do FPU operations in parallel" as "half-true". In some senses and under certain conditions, it is completely true; in other senses, it is not true at all. So to make the general statement is very misleading and very likely to be misinterpreted.

Now, most likely, your teacher said this in a very specific context, making some assumptions about what (s)he had already told you previously, and you didn't include all of that in the question, so I won't blame them for being intentionally misleading. Instead, I will try to clarify this general claim, pointing out some ways in which it is true and other ways in which it is false.

The big sticking point is exactly what is meant by "FPU operations". Classically, x86 processors have done FPU operations on a separate floating-point coprocessor (known as a floating-point unit, or FPU), the x87. Up until the 80486 processor, this was a separate chip installed on the main board. Starting with the 80486DX, the x87 FPU was integrated directly onto the same silicon as the main processor and was therefore available on all systems, instead of just those that had a specialized x87 FPU installed. This remains true today—all x86 processors have a built-in x87-compatible FPU, and this is generally what people refer to when they say "FPU" in the context of the x86 microarchitecture.

However, the x87 FPU is rarely used anymore for floating-point operations. Although it is still there, it has effectively been superseded by a SIMD unit that is both easier to program for and (in general) more efficient.

AMD was the first to introduce such a specialized vector unit with their 3DNow! technology in the K6-2 microprocessor (circa 1998). For various technical and marketing reasons, this didn't really get used, except in certain games and other specialized applications, and never caught on in the industry (AMD has since phased it out on modern processors), but it did support arithmetic operations on packed, single-precision floating-point values.

SIMD really began to catch on when Intel released the SSE extension with the Pentium III processor. SSE was similar to 3DNow!, in that it supported vector operations on single-precision floating-point values, but was incompatible with it and supported a slightly larger range of operations. AMD quickly added SSE support to their processors, too. The really nice thing about SSE compared to 3DNow! was that it used a completely separate set of registers, which made programming much easier. With the Pentium 4, Intel released SSE2, which was an extension of SSE that added support for double-precision floating-point values. SSE2 is supported by *all* processors that support the 64-bit long mode extensions (AMD64), which is all processors made today, so 64-bit code virtually *always* uses SSE2 instructions to manipulate floating-point values, rather than x87 instructions. Even in 32-bit code, SSE2 instructions are in common use today, since all processors since the Pentium 4 have supported them.

Aside from support for legacy processors, there is really only one reason to use x87 instructions today, and that is that the x87 FPU supported a special "long double" format, with 80 bits of precision. SSE supports only single-precision (32-bit), while SSE2 added support for double-precision (64-bit) values. If you absolutely need extended precision, then the x87 is your best option. (At the level of individual instructions, it is comparable in speed to the SIMD units operating on scalar values.) Otherwise, you prefer SSE/SSE2 (and later SIMD extensions to the instruction set, like AVX, etc.) And, of course, when I say "you", I don't just mean assembly-language programmers; I also mean compilers. For example, Visual Studio 2010 was the last major version to emit x87 code by default for 32-bit builds. In all later versions, SSE2 instructions are generated unless you specifically turn them off (`/arch:IA32`).

With these SIMD instructions, it is entirely true that multiple floating-point operations can be done simultaneously—in fact, that is the whole point. And even when you're working with scalar (non-packed) floating-point values, as in the code you've shown, modern processors generally have multiple execution units that allow multiple operations to be done simultaneously (assuming certain conditions are met, like a lack of data dependencies, as you point out, and also which specific instructions are being executed [some instructions can only be executed on certain units, limiting the amount of true parallelism]).

But as I said before, the reason I term this claim misleading is because when someone says "FPU", it is generally understood to mean the x87 FPU, and in that case, the options for independent, parallel execution are *substantially* more limited. x87 FPU instructions are all the ones whose mnemonics begin with `f`, including `FADD`, `FMUL`, `FDIV`, `FLD`, `FSTP`, etc. These instructions *cannot* pair<sup>*</sup> and therefore can never be executed truly independently.

There is only one special exception to the rule that x87 FPU instructions cannot pair, and that is the `FXCH` instruction (floating-point exchange). `FXCH` *can* pair when it occurs as the second instruction in a pair, *as long as* the first instruction in the pair is either `FLD`, `FADD`, `FSUB`, `FMUL`, `FDIV`, `FCOM`, `FCHS`, or `FABS`, *and* the next instruction following `FXCHG` is also a floating-point instruction. So, this does cover the most common cases where you would use `FXCHG`. As [Iwillnotexist Idonotexist alluded to in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093558/independent-fpu-operations#comment75208994_44093558), this magic is implemented internally via register renaming: the `FXCH` instruction does not actually swap the contents of the two registers, as you might imagine; it only swaps the names of the registers. On the Pentium and later processors, registers can be renamed while they are in use, and can even be renamed more than once per clock, without incurring any stalls. This feature is actually very important to maintaining top performance in x87 code. Why? Well, the x87 is unusual in that it has a stack-based interface. Its "registers" (`st0` through `st7`) are implemented as a stack, and several floating-point instructions operate only on the value at the top of the stack (`st0`). But a feature that allows you to use the stack-based interface of the FPU in a reasonably efficient manner hardly counts as "independent" execution.

However, it is true that many x87 FPU operations can *overlap*. This works just like any other type of instruction: since the Pentium, x86 processors have been *pipelined*, which effectively means that instructions execute in many different stages. (The longer the pipeline, the more stages of execution, which means the more instructions the processor can be working on at a time, which also generally means the faster the processor can be clocked. However, it has other disadvantages, like higher penalties for mispredicted branches, but I digress.) So, although each instruction still takes a fixed number of cycles to complete, it is possible for an instruction to begin executing before the previous one has finished. For example:

```
fadd  st(1), st(0)    ; clock cycles 1 through 3
fadd  st(2), st(0)    ; clock cycles 2 through 4
fadd  st(3), st(0)    ; clock cycles 3 through 5
fadd  st(4), st(0)    ; clock cycles 4 through 6
```

The `FADD` instruction takes 3 clock cycles to execute, but we can start a new `FADD` on each clock cycle. As you can see, it is possible to do up to 4 `FADD` operations in only 6 clock cycles, which is twice as fast as the 12 clock cycles that this would take on a non-pipelined FPU.

Naturally, as you say in the question, this overlapping requires that there are no dependencies between the two instructions. In other words, two instructions cannot be overlapped if the second one requires the result of the first. In practice, this unfortunately means that the gains from this pipelining are limited. Because of the FPU's stack-based architecture that I mentioned earlier, and the fact that most floating-point instructions involve the value at the top of the stack (`st(0)`), there are extremely few cases where it is possible for an instruction to be independent of the previous instruction's result.

The way around this conundrum is the pairing of the `FXCH` instruction that I mentioned earlier, which makes it possible to interleave multiple, independent calculations if you are *extremely* careful and clever in your scheduling. Agner Fog, in an old version of his classic [optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) gives the following example:

```
fld  [a1]   ; cycle 1
fadd [a2]   ; cycles 2-4
fld  [b1]   ; cycle 3
fadd [b2]   ; cycles 4-6
fld  [c1]   ; cycle 5
fadd [c2]   ; cycles 6-8
fxch st(2)  ; cycle 6 (pairs with previous instruction)
fadd [a3]   ; cycles 7-9
fxch st(1)  ; cycle 7 (pairs with previous instruction)
fadd [b3]   ; cycles 8-10
fxch st(2)  ; cycle 8 (pairs with previous instruction)
fadd [c3]   ; cycles 9-11
fxch st(1)  ; cycle 9 (pairs with previous instruction)
fadd [a4]   ; cycles 10-12
fxch st(2)  ; cycle 10 (pairs with previous instruction)
fadd [b4]   ; cycles 11-13
fxch st(1)  ; cycle 11 (pairs with previous instruction)
fadd [c4]   ; cycles 12-14
fxch st(2)  ; cycle 12 (pairs with previous instruction)
```

In this code, three independent computations have been interleaved: (`a1` + `a2` + `a3` + `a4`), (`b1` + `b2` + `b3` + `b4`), and (`c1` + `c2` + `c3` + `c4`). Since each `FADD` takes 3 clock cycles, after we kick off the `a` computation, we have two "free" cycles to start two new `FADD` instructions for the `b` and `c` computations before returning to the `a` computation. Every third `FADD` instruction returns to the original computation, following a regular pattern. In between, `FXCH` instructions are used to make the top of the stack (`st(0)`) contain the value that belongs to the appropriate computation. Equivalent code could be written for `FSUB`, `FMUL`, and `FILD`, since all three take 3 clock cycles and are able to overlap. (Well, except that, at least on the Pentium—I'm not sure if this holds true on later processors, since I don't use the x87 anymore—the `FMUL` instruction is not perfectly pipelined, so you cannot start an `FMUL` one clock cycle after another `FMUL`. You either have a stall, or you have to throw another instruction in-between.)

I imagine that this kind of thing is what your teacher had in mind. In practice, though, even with the magic of the `FXCHG` instruction, it is quite difficult to write code that truly achieves significant levels of parallelism. You need to have multiple independent computations that you can interleave, but in many cases, you are just calculating a single, big formula. There are sometimes ways to compute pieces of the formula independently, in parallel, and then combine them at the end, but you will inevitably have stalls in there that reduce the overall performance, and not all floating-point instructions can overlap. As you might imagine, this is so difficult to achieve that compilers rarely do (to any significant extent). It requires a human with the determination and fortitude to hand-optimize the code, manually scheduling and interleaving the instructions.

One thing that *is* more often possible is interleaving floating-point and integer instructions. Instructions like `FDIV` are slow (~39 cycles on the Pentium) and do not overlap well with other floating-point instructions; however, it can overlap with integer instructions on all but its first clock cycle. (There are always caveats, and this is no exception: floating-point division cannot be overlapped with integer division because they are handled by the same execution unit on almost all processors.) Something similar could be done with `FSQRT`. Compilers are somewhat more likely to perform these types of optimizations, assuming that you have written the code where integer operations are interspersed around floating-point operations (inlining helps dramatically with this), but still, in many cases where you're doing extended floating-point computations, you have little integer work that needs to be done.

---

Now that you have a better understanding of the complexities of achieving truly "independent" floating-point operations, and why the `FADD`+`FMUL` code you wrote doesn't actually overlap or perform any faster, let me briefly address the problems you ran into when trying to look at the output from a compiler.

(By the way, this is a *great* strategy and one of the primary ways that I learned how to write and optimize assembly code. And building on a compiler's output is still how I start when I want to hand-optimize a particular snippet of code.)

As I mentioned above, modern compilers don't generate x87 FPU instructions. They *never* do for 64-bit builds, so you must start by compiling in 32-bit mode. Then, you generally have to specify a compiler switch that instructs it not to use SSE instructions. In MSVC, this is `/arch:IA32`. In Gnu-style compilers, like GCC and Clang, this is `-mfpmath=387` and/or `-mno-sse`.

There is one other little niggle that explains what you were actually seeing. The C code you were writing used the `float` type, which is a single-precision (32-bit) type. As you learned above, the x87 FPU uses a special 80-bit "extended" precision internally. That mismatch in precision can affect the output of floating-point operations, so to strictly comply with the IEEE-754 and language-specific standards, compilers default to a "strict" or "precise" mode when using the x87 FPU where they flush the precision of each intermediate operation to 32-bit. This is why you see the pattern you see:

```
flds    -4(%ebp)
fadds   -8(%ebp) # i = a + b
fstps   -32(%ebp)
```

It loads a single-precision value at the top of the FPU stack, implicitly extending that value to have 80-bit precision. This is the `FLDS` instruction. Then, the `FADDS` instruction does a combination load-and-add: it first loads a single-precision value, implicitly extending it to have 80-bit precision, and adds that to the value at the top of the FPU stack. Finally, it pops the result to a temporary location in memory, flushing it to a 32-bit, single-precision value.

You're entirely right that you won't get *any* parallelism with code like this. Even basic overlapping becomes impossible. But code like this is generated for *precision*, not for speed. [All sorts of other optimizations are disabled, too, in the name of correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa).

If you want to prevent this and get the fastest floating-point code possible, even at the expense of correctness, then you need to pass a flag to indicate this to the compiler. On MSVC, this is `/fp:fast`. On Gnu-style compilers, like GCC and Clang, this is `-ffast-math`.

A couple of other related tips:

- When you're analyzing compiler-generated disassembly, *always* make sure that you're looking at optimized code. Don't bother with unoptimized code; it's very noisy, will just confuse you, and doesn't match what a real assembly programmer would actually write. For MSVC, then, use the `/O2` switch; for GCC/Clang, use the `-O2` or `-O3` switches.
- Unless you just really like the AT&T syntax, configure your Gnu compiler or disassembler to emit Intel-format syntax listings. These will ensure that the output looks like the code you would see in Intel's manuals or other books on assembly-language programming. For the compiler, use the options `-S -masm=intel`. For `objdump`, use the options `-d -M intel`. This isn't necessary with Microsoft's compiler, as it never uses AT&T syntax.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Starting with the Pentium processor (circa 1993), integer instructions executed on the main part of the processor could be "paired". This was accomplished by the processor actually having two mostly-independent execution units, known as the "U" pipe and the "V" pipe. There were naturally some caveats to this pairing—the "V" pipe was more limited in the instructions that it could execute than the "U" pipe, and so certain instructions and certain combinations of instructions were non-pairable—but in general, this possibility of pairing doubled the effective bandwidth of the Pentium, making it significantly faster than its predecessor (the 486) on code that had been written accordingly. What I'm saying here is that, in contrast to the main integer side of the processor, the x87 FPU did *not* support this type of pairing.</sub>

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you, I will try to somehow correct my code, maybe try your thought from Fogs book. And this AT&T syntax - they just force me to use it, so I cannot really switch to Intels