# Operator overloading associativity compiler optimization

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, compiler-optimization, associativity

I'm not familiar with the details of how the addition and multiplication operators are defined in C++, and I also don't know what information is or is not available to the compiler to optimize out inefficient orders of operation.

Let's say we have a matrix datatype with an implementation of element-wise multiplication by a scalar (i.e scaling the matrix by a scalar). If we have the following code snippet:

```
Matrix a;
float b = /* value set at runtime */;
float c = /* value set at runtime */;
a = a * b * c;
```

If we naively evaluated this expression left-to-right, we would first scale `a` by `b` and then scale it by `c` rather than scaling `a` by the product of `b` and `c`. Is the compiler capable of selecting the latter 
(more efficient) behavior instead of the former?

Comment: The compiler doesn't generally understand the semantics of user-defined functions. It would take an automatic theorem prover to prove that rewriting the expression to `a * c * b` doesn't change its meaning; it's highly unlikely that the compiler would be able to pull it off.

Comment: I recall hearing a story of some kind of experimental compiler that was able to rewrite `int s = 0; for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) s += i;` to `s = n*(n+1)/2;` I strongly suspect it was an urban legend.

Comment: If C++ defines multiplication and addition as operations that must be associative, then I'd assume it's fair game for the compiler to rewrite the expression as `a * (b * c)` or `c * a * b`. Of course, the compiler would have to be able to determine that one of these orderings is more efficient. Again, I don't know much about compiler optimization, so this is just speculation.

Comment: Hmm I just noticed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa?rq=1 . Still don't know if -fassociative-math would help

Comment: C++ makes certain assumptions about *built-in* operators. User-defined overloaded operators are just functions with funny names; no assumption is made about their behavior. `a * b * c` is merely a shorthand for `operator*(operator*(a, b), c)`; I assume your program defines `operator*(float, Matrix)` and `operator*(Matrix, float)` alonside `class Matrix`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some experimentation on Godbolt appears to find that recent versions of GCC and Clang generate the same code for `a * b * c` as it does for `(a * b) * c`, which is longer than what it generates for `a * (b * c)`, therefore it appears that no, compilers are not smart enough to perform the optimization you're asking about.

You could just parenthesize `b * c` yourself. A more complicated solution is to have the `*` operator generate an expression template that will be optimized before evaluation, so even if the user types `(a * b) * c` your library will rearrange it to `a * (b * c)` before evaluating it.

Comment: It's not so much that they're not "smart enough". More like they're not that dumb. It would result it different behavior and violate the C++ spec, because floats aren't often exact representations, multiplication is not associative. Even if `a`, `b`, and `c` were all floats with no Matrix involved.

Comment: @paulpro most compilers have flags to permit associativity on floating point multiplication even if it changes results.