# What does computationally associative mean?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

K&R's C language has the following sentence:

> A compiler's license to treat mathematically associative operators as computationally associative is revoked.

This is in the Appendix C, which tells what's different from before ANSI C. But I don't know how computationally associated is different from mathematically associated. Maybe I guess the mathematically associative is *a * b * c = (a * b) * c* (left), or *a * (b * c)* (right).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa answer your question?

Comment: It's saying that even though `a * (b * c)` is equal to `(a * b) * c` mathematically, the compiler is not allowed to replace one with the other and must evaluate (compute) the multiplication as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a = 0x1p64;  //  Two the power of 64, 18,446,744,073,709,551,616.
    double b = 1;
    double c = -a;
    printf("%g\n", a+b+c);
}
```

In the C grammar, `a+b+c` is equivalent to `(a+b)+c`, so `a` and `b` are added first, and then `c` is added. In the format commonly used for `double`, `a+b` yields 2<sup>64</sup>, not 2<sup>64</sup>+1, because the `double` format does not have enough precision to represent 2<sup>64</sup>+1, so the result of the addition is the ideal mathematical result rounded to the nearest representable value, which is 2<sup>64</sup>. Then adding `c` yields zero, so “0” is printed.

If instead we calculated `a+c+b`, adding `a` and `c` would give zero, and then adding `b` would give one, and “1” would be printed.

Thus, floating-point operations are not generally associative; `a+b+c` is not the same as `a+c+b`.

In ordinary mathematics with real numbers, *a*+*b*+*c* is the same as *a*+*c*+*b*; addition of real numbers is associative.

Prior to standardization, some C compilers would treat floating-point expressions as if operators were associative (for those operators whose counterparts in real-number-arithmetic were associative). The C standard does not permit that in implementations that conform to the standard. Conforming compilers must produce results as if the operations were performed in the order specified by the C grammar.

Some compilers may still treat floating-point operators as associative when operating in non-standard modes, which may be selected by flags or switches passed to the compiler. Also, because the C standard allows implementations to perform floating-point arithmetic with more precision than the nominal type (e.g., when computing `a+b+c`, it can calculate it as if the types were `long double` instead of `double`), that can produce results that are the same as if operations were rearranged, so you can still get results that look like operators have been reordered associatively, depending on the C implementation and the flags used.