# Can I make my compiler use fast-math on a per-function basis?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, nvcc, fast-math, template-instantiation

Suppose I have

```
template <bool UsesFastMath> void foo(float* data, size_t length);
```

and I want to compile one instantiation with `-ffast-math` (`--use-fast-math` for nvcc), and the other instantiation without it.

This can be achieved by instantiating each of the variants in a separate translation unit, and compiling each of them with a different command-line - with and without the switch.

My question is whether it's possible to indicate to popular compilers (*) to apply or not apply `-ffast-math` for individual functions - so that I'll be able to have my instantiations in the same translation unit.

**Notes:**

- If the answer is "no", bonus points for explaining why not.
- This is not the same questions as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18197344/1593077), which is about turning fast-math on and off at runtime. I'm much more modest...

---

(*) by popular compilers I mean any of: gcc, clang, msvc icc, nvcc (for GPU kernel code) about which you have that information.

Comment: `nvcc`: No. Compilation flags are applied on a per-compilation-unit basis. No equivalent function attributes exist to apply this on a per-function basis. If you want different flags applied, stick the code into different compilation units (you can include the source code from the same file, if you desire). For tight local control, various CUDA device intrinsics (or worst case, some inline assembly) can provide much of what you need.

Comment: I have supplied an answer as suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of CUDA 7.5 (the latest version I am familiar with, although CUDA 8.0 is currently shipping), `nvcc` does *not* support function attributes that allow programmers to apply specific compiler optimizations on a per-function basis.

Since optimization configurations set via command line switches apply to the entire compilation unit, one possible approach is to use as many different compilation units as there are different optimization configurations, as already noted in the question; source code may be shared and `#include`-ed from a common file.

With `nvcc`, the command line switch `--use_fast_math` basically controls three areas of functionality:

- Flush-to-zero mode is enabled (that is, denormal support is disabled)
- Single-precision reciprocal, division, and square root are switched to approximate versions
- Certain standard math functions are replaced by equivalent, lower-precision, intrinsics

You can apply some of these changes with per-operation granularity by using appropriate intrinsics, others by using PTX inline assembly.

Comment: It's the same for CUDA 8.0 AFAICT.

Answer (score 12):

In GCC you can declare functions like following:

```
__attribute__((optimize("-ffast-math")))
double
myfunc(double val)
{
    return val / 2;
}
```

This is GCC-only feature.

See working example here -> https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-10/msg00385.html

It seems that GCC not verifies optimize() arguments. So typos like "-ffast-match" will be silently ignored.

Comment: "GCC-only feature" - that just means it doesn't follow from any public standard, right? Or are you also saying that, say, clang doesn't have such a feature?

Comment: I think it implies both at the same time