# Enable fast-math in Clang on a per-function basis?

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

GCC provides a way to optimize a function/section of code selectively with
`fast-math` using  [attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2009-10/msg00385.html). Is there a way to enable the same in Clang with pragmas/attributes?
I understand Clang provides some  [pragmas](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extensions-to-specify-floating-point-flags)
to specify floating point flags. However, none of these pragmas enable `fast-math`.

PS: A similar question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699071/can-i-make-my-compiler-use-fast-math-on-a-per-function-basis?noredirect=1&lq=1) but was not answered in the context of Clang.

Answer (score 0):

UPD: I missed that you mentioned pragmas. The Option1 is fast math for one op as far as I understood. I am not sure about flushing subnormals, I hope it's not affected.

I didn't find the per function options, but I did find 2 pragmas that can help.

Let's say we want dot product.

Option 1.

```
float innerProductF32(const float* a, const float* b, std::size_t size) {
  float res = 0.f;

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
#pragma float_control(precise, off)
    res += a[i] * b[i];
  }
  return res;
}
```

Option2:

```
float innerProductF32(const float* a, const float* b, std::size_t size) {
  float res = 0.f;

  _Pragma("clang loop vectorize(enable) interleave(enable)")
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    res += a[i] * b[i];
  }
  return res;
}
```

The second one is less powerful, it does not generate `fma` instructions, but maybe it's not what you want.