# Optimization flags for floating point arithmetic and GPU for android

Tags: android, floating-point, gpu, compiler-optimization

I am performing floating point and GPU operations using C++ on android. I would like to know what are the various compiler optimization flags to improve speed of execution of these operations , I just want to make the native code more faster using compiler flags and learn more about these flags.

The flags that I have found so far which improve my operations:

```
-std=c++11 
-mtune=arm7
-mfpu=vfpv3-d16 
-mfloat-abi=softfp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -ffast-math if you can garantee to the compiler that your code is safe from [these optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135559/2726154).

Also take a look from Android documentation about [NEON](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-arm-neon.html). NEON with -ffast-math will allow the compiler to do automatic vectorization of your code