# how to use the gcc preprocessor macro __FAST_MATH__?

Tags: math, gcc, optimization, c-preprocessor

man gcc(1) says: the option -ffast-math causes the preprocessor macro __FAST_MATH__ to be defined. Is there any further documentation of that macro?

I would expect that code like

```
#define __FAST_MATH__ blabla
y = pow(x,a);
#undef __FAST_MATH__
```

allows control of math optimization, fine grained down to single statements.

However, my tests rather indicate that

```
#define __FAST_MATH__
#define __FAST_MATH__ on
```

are all ignored, regardless where they are placed.

[EDIT] They are ignored even if they are placed *before*

```
#include <math.h>
```

"Ignored" means: have no measurable effect. Whereas -ffast-math accelerates my test code by a factor of 3.

Comment: If you use `-ffast-math`, then `__FAST_MATH__` is defined. That's probably all there is to it and it has no further effect.

Comment: I would guess that the header math.h contains some #ifdef __FAST_MATH somewhere? Also, I would still think that something internal to the compiler behaves differently with -ffast-math.

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do has a lot of information on what the flag actually does.

Comment: @Uli: Indeed, ``#ifdef __FAST_MATH__`` appears in math.h, in x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathinline.h, and in more locations. It also appears in independent projects like Eigen3 or boost/math.

Comment: @Salixalba: My question was not about what the flag does. My question was: can one achieve the same effect in a more fine-grained way by using the preprocessor macro *instead of* the flag.... And the answer seems to be very simple: No, one cannot.

Comment: If its fine-grained control you are after you might be able to explicitly call specific library functions. For example, the [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/readme) library has a number of different entry points for specific implementations of each maths functions. It has SVID, X/OPEN, or POSIX/ANSI version of the different functions. You are likely to loose portability though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have it backwards. The macro is defined in order for the standard library to use different implementations of the math functions.

Defining it yourself has no effect and might actually be dangerously buggy because the program would be using those alternate implementations when the compiler is not generating the expected code.

Comment: Using `__FAST_MATH__` in the standard library wouln't work as expected, because you'll need `-ffast-math` as multilib option, i.e. you need 2 different variants (or even more if there are more multilib variants like for 32-bit, 64-bit etc.) of the libraries which would be selected by `-f[no-]fast-math`, respectively. Use `gcc -print-multi-lib` to show the multilib layout. `-ffast-math` (would be encoded as `@fast-math)` is not mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

> `-ffast-math` causes the preprocessor macro `__FAST_MATH__` to be defined.

It's just a feature-test macro, i.e. you can use conditional compilation depending on whether you specified `-ffast-math` or not:

```
#if defined (__FAST_MATH__)
/* Code to use with -ffast-math. */
#else
/* Code to use with -fno-fast-math. */
#endif /* -ffast-math ? */
```

In most cases, you won't need conditional compilation, but if you need it, you have a macro handy and don't need to define it in your code or per `-D` on the command line.

Moreover, some (system) headers might depend on it and use faster code provided `-ffast-math` is on.

More common such macros are `__OPTIMIZE__` and `__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__`.  The former is defined if optimization is on (`-Og`, `-O1`, `-O2`, `-Os`, ...), the latter when optimizing for size is on per `-Os`.

**Note:** Making use of such options in the standard library would only work as expected when `-ffast-math` was introduced as a multilib option, so that specifying it would link different incarnations of libc, libm, libstdc++, etc. like with `-m32` / `-m64`. You can display the multilib layout with `gcc -print-multi-lib` which yields on my x86_64:

```
.;
32;@m32
```

This means we have 2 variants, a default one and one picked with `-m32`.