# Best way calculating remainder on floating points

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, cmath

## Question

What is the computational cost of the [`remainder`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/remainder/) function, is there a specific instruction to calculate it in a cheap way in a specific case?

## Description

I need to transform a mathematical variable *x* into the range of *I*=[-0.5; 0.5) from *R*=[-2; 2). While *x* is not element of *I*, then *x* is shifted towards *I* by repeatedly adding or subtracting 1 to the value of *x*. *x* is represented with `double x` in my code. I need the fastest way of this transformation for this *I* and *R* values but wider *R* ranges can be also interesting.

## Ideas and speed comparison

The function I was suggested to use was the naive implementation following the description:

```
void shift_to_I(double& x) // version 1
{
    while (x < -0.5)
            x += 1;

    while (x >= 0.5)
            x -= 1;
}
```

Not only for speed considerations but also for code quality I was thinking of using [`remainder`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/remainder/) from `<cmath>` introduced in c++11. With `remainder` the code shortens to

```
void shift_to_I(double& x) // version 2
{
    x = remainder(x,1);
}
```

I had to realize though that it was slower than the original function on my architecture (Intel i7 whatver with VC++). I believed there was a dedicated instruction for this purpose, but either the compiler doesn't know it or it doesn't exist. For wider *R* interval (on my architecture it is around [-25; 25)) the second version will be faster but I need a code that is fast for narrow intervals too. clang and gcc specific solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: note that there is also `std::fmod`, i didnt understand the difference, but it is not the same as `std::remainder`

Comment: Note that special functions line `remainder` and `fmod` have to deal properly with corner cases like `inf` and `nan`.

Comment: `x -= int(x);` would reduce to `(-1, 1)` interval without a loop; it would take another operation to get to (-0.5, 0.5). No idea how well this will perform; you may want to benchmark. This should perform the same independent of the width of `R` (as long as it's within `int` range).

Comment: The Intel x86 and x64 CPUs (FPUs) have the `fprem` and `fprem1` [instructions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fprem1) (single op, gets remainder). But whether or not a particular compiler uses these for `std::remainder()` (or `std::fmod()`) depends on their implementers' decisions.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The only difference seem to be that _"In contrast to std::fmod(), the returned value is not guaranteed to have the same sign as x."_ (where x is the first parameter) from (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder)

Comment: Why not use both solutions?  Check the range, if it is small, use the naive approach, if it is large, use the other.  A good way to tune this is to use google benchmark to test the performance of the code.

Comment: "I had to realize though that it was slower than the original function" - Did you test that with an optimized build or only with a debug build?

Comment: @JesperJuhl with Release mode. I also paid attention not to optimize out variables (collecting sum e.g.) and to measure on 1e8 random numbers uniformly distributed in *R*.

Comment: @Evg I believe due to IEEE specs, the implementer must take care of those silly cases except one turns on `-ffast-math`. In this case, do you think the implementer removes those code parts checking for `nan`s and `inf`s? But clearly, `fmod` is not the right function here.

Comment: With `-ffast-math` GCC issues just a single assembly instruction, no special checks for `inf` and `nan` are performed. But Clang still calls `__ieee754_remainder`.

Comment: @Evg While `-ffast-math` is nice and fast and all, the *unpleasant* part of it is that it breaks standard conformance. Personally I avoid it. I'll rather have standard guaranteed behaviour than slightly better performance with sometimes surprising results. But of course, *sometimes* you know what you are doing and know that the `fast-math` shortcuts don't affect you and the extra perf is super important, in that case, sure; use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is compiler and implementation dependent.

For example, on my machine with GCC 8.3:

1. **Without** [`-ffast-math`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do), `std::remainder` translates into a call to [this function](https://github.com/ctf-wiki/glibc/blob/master/math/w_remainder_compat.c):

   ```
   double __remainder(double x, double y)
   {
       if (((__builtin_expect (y == 0.0, 0) && ! isnan(x)) || (__builtin_expect(isinf(x), 0) && ! isnan(y))) && _LIB_VERSION != _IEEE_)
           return __kernel_standard(x, y, 28);
       return __ieee754_remainder(x, y);
   }
   ```

   with `__ieee754_remainder` looking like [this](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_remainder.c):

   ```
   double __ieee754_remainder(double x, double y)
   {
       double z, d, xx;
       int4 kx, ky, n, nn, n1, m1, l;
       mynumber u, t, w = {{0, 0}}, v = {{0, 0}}, ww = {{0, 0}}, r;
       u.x = x;
       t.x = y;
       kx = u.i[HIGH_HALF] & 0x7fffffff; /* no sign  for x*/
       t.i[HIGH_HALF] &= 0x7fffffff;     /*no sign for y */
       ky = t.i[HIGH_HALF];
       /*------ |x| < 2^1023  and   2^-970 < |y| < 2^1024 ------------------*/
       if (kx < 0x7fe00000 && ky < 0x7ff00000 && ky >= 0x03500000)
       {
           SET_RESTORE_ROUND_NOEX(FE_TONEAREST);
           if (kx + 0x00100000 < ky)
               return x;
           if ((kx - 0x01500000) < ky)
           {
               z = x / t.x;
               v.i[HIGH_HALF] = t.i[HIGH_HALF];
               d = (z + big.x) - big.x;
               xx = (x - d * v.x) - d * (t.x - v.x);
               if (d - z != 0.5 && d - z != -0.5)
                   return (xx != 0) ? xx : ((x > 0) ? ZERO.x : nZERO.x);
               else
               {
                   if (fabs(xx) > 0.5 * t.x)
                       return (z > d) ? xx - t.x : xx + t.x;
                   else
                       return xx;
               }
           } /*    (kx<(ky+0x01500000))         */
           else
           {
               r.x = 1.0 / t.x;
               n = t.i[HIGH_HALF];
               nn = (n & 0x7ff00000) + 0x01400000;
               w.i[HIGH_HALF] = n;
               ww.x = t.x - w.x;
               l = (kx - nn) & 0xfff00000;
               n1 = ww.i[HIGH_HALF];
               m1 = r.i[HIGH_HALF];
               while (l > 0)
               {
                   r.i[HIGH_HALF] = m1 - l;
                   z = u.x * r.x;
                   w.i[HIGH_HALF] = n + l;
                   ww.i[HIGH_HALF] = (n1) ? n1 + l : n1;
                   d = (z + big.x) - big.x;
                   u.x = (u.x - d * w.x) - d * ww.x;
                   l = (u.i[HIGH_HALF] & 0x7ff00000) - nn;
               }
               r.i[HIGH_HALF] = m1;
               w.i[HIGH_HALF] = n;
               ww.i[HIGH_HALF] = n1;
               z = u.x * r.x;
               d = (z + big.x) - big.x;
               u.x = (u.x - d * w.x) - d * ww.x;
               if (fabs(u.x) < 0.5 * t.x)
                   return (u.x != 0) ? u.x : ((x > 0) ? ZERO.x : nZERO.x);
                   else if (fabs(u.x) > 0.5 * t.x)
                   return (d > z) ? u.x + t.x : u.x - t.x;
               else
               {
                   z = u.x / t.x;
                   d = (z + big.x) - big.x;
                   return ((u.x - d * w.x) - d * ww.x);
               }
           }
       } /*   (kx<0x7fe00000&&ky<0x7ff00000&&ky>=0x03500000)     */
       else
       {
           if (kx < 0x7fe00000 && ky < 0x7ff00000 && (ky > 0 || t.i[LOW_HALF] != 0))
           {
               y = fabs(y) * t128.x;
               z = __ieee754_remainder(x, y) * t128.x;
               z = __ieee754_remainder(z, y) * tm128.x;
               return z;
           }
           else
           {
               if ((kx & 0x7ff00000) == 0x7fe00000 && ky < 0x7ff00000 &&
                   (ky > 0 || t.i[LOW_HALF] != 0))
               {
                   y = fabs(y);
                   z = 2.0 * __ieee754_remainder(0.5 * x, y);
                   d = fabs(z);
                   if (d <= fabs(d - y))
                       return z;
                   else if (d == y)
                       return 0.0 * x;
                   else
                       return (z > 0) ? z - y : z + y;
               }
               else /* if x is too big */
               {
                   if (ky == 0 && t.i[LOW_HALF] == 0) /* y = 0 */
                       return (x * y) / (x * y);
                   else if (kx >= 0x7ff00000    /* x not finite */
                            || (ky > 0x7ff00000 /* y is NaN */
                                   || (ky == 0x7ff00000 && t.i[LOW_HALF] != 0)))
                       return (x * y) / (x * y);
                   else
                       return x;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Pretty far from a single machine instruction.
2. **With** `-ffast-math`, single `fprem1` assembly instruction is used.

Comment: With a little benchmark using `-ffast-math`, I got that in case *R* = [-2; 2), `remainder` function is faster than the loop-based one by 10%. For *R* = [-1.5; 1.5), the `remainder` is slower and the loop-based is faster, again, around 10%.

Comment: @DanielTuzes, and without `-ffast-math`?