# C++ calculate the power of a number without using pow or loop

Tags: c++, function, loops, exponent

I am a beginner C++ user and have been given a task to code a function that calculates the power of a number but we are not allowed to use the pow function or a loop.

The user of the function has to input the base and exponent in the command window.

What is a good place to start?

Comment: something that needs a loop but you are not allowed to use a loop should ring a bell called: recursion

Comment: If not loop then it's recursion.

Comment: And in the real world, you learn how to convert ill-advised recursion back to loops. The two are mathematically related, but reality has a strong preference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pow(x, y)` can be written as `exp(y * log(x))`. As far as I can tell that satisfies the question constraints.

With real `x` and `y`, any alternative to that is difficult. Sure, there are silly alternatives using recursion for integral `y` but using recursion for linear problems is never a particularly good approach.

Comment: i like this spirit. Teachers asking silly questions should be ready to accept clever answers ;)

Comment: @Shawn not really although clearly it’s related otherwise this answer would not be possible. From a mathematical standpoint exp(x) can be defined as a function whose value equals its gradient.

Comment: ...with a condition `exp(0)=1`.

Answer (score 4):

```
void start_here(unsigned int n) {
    if (n > 0)
        start_here(n - 1);
}

start_here(2019);
```

Then you write:

```
double pow(double x, unsigned int exp) {
    if (exp > 0)
        return x * pow(x, exp - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Then you improve:

```
double pow(double x, unsigned int exp) {
    if (exp > 0) {
        const auto p2 = pow(x, exp / 2);        
        return p2 * p2 * ((exp & 1) ? x : 1);
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

The last algorithm is known as binary exponentiation.

And finally you learn templates:

```
template<unsigned int exp>
constexpr double pow(double x) {
    if constexpr (exp > 0) {
        const auto p2 = pow<exp / 2>(x);        
        return p2 * p2 * ((exp & 1) ? x : 1);
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

---

**Edit.** Tail recursion optimization.
Let's take a look at the assembly code generated for the first version of 
`pow()` without optimizations (`-O0`):

```
pow(double, unsigned int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], edi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
        je      .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        lea     edx, [rax-1]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     edi, edx
        movq    xmm0, rax
        call    pow(double, unsigned int)
        mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
.L3:
        leave
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248
```

We see a recursive `call pow(double, unsigned int)`.

Now let's add some optimizations (`-O2 -ffast-math`):

```
pow(double, unsigned int):
        movapd  xmm1, xmm0
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        test    edi, edi
        je      .L4
.L3:
        mulsd   xmm0, xmm1
        sub     edi, 1
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248
```

Where is the recursive call? It's gone! The compiler employs the [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) and transforms a recursive call into a simple loop. This assembly code is equivalent to this C++ one:

```
double pow(double x, unsigned int exp) {
    double p = 1;
    if (exp == 0)
        return p;
  loop:
    p *= x;
    if (--exp > 0)
       goto loop;
    return p;     
}
```

This optimization is not possible without [`-ffast-math` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do) due to non-associativity of floating point multiplication.

And finally, `1.d`'s is represented in memory by 8 bytes:

```
3F F0 00 00 | 00 00 00 00  (base 16)
```

After conversion into two `long` numbers, they become:

```
1072693248  | 0            (base 10)
```

These are two magic numbers that can be spotted in the assembly code.

Comment: Yup, upvote for exponentation by squaring. Bonus point if you mention the possibility of tail recursion optimisation.

Comment: @Bathsheba, added a few words and a couple of references.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will do it.

```
int exponent(int , int );

int main()
{
    cout<<exponent(3,8);
    return 0;
}
int exponent(int x , int y )
{
    if(y==0)
        return 1;
    return (x*exponent(x,y-1));
}
```

Let me know if you found it hard to digest.

Comment: hm I dont think this is what OP will **do**. I rather think it is too tempting to simply copy your code. Please at least explain what the code does

Comment: Using` int` means your function is vulnerable to overflow.

Comment: It is not only integers that can be raised to a power, and nor are powers required to be integers.

Comment: @Bathsheba  why it's an overflow. i haven't stored exponent anywhere? I'm just returning it.

Comment: The largest `int` can be as small as 32767. Surprisingly small `x` and `y` will cause that. At the very least use an `unsigned` type.

Comment: So what's the deal ? No one is going to compute 32767 ^ 32767 using recursion.

Comment: I can't write unsigned power can be negative. Writing unigned will make overflow.

Comment: why not? No such constraints are mentioned in the question, but yet you suggest to use recursion ;)

Comment: Note : you might want to compute `exponent(x,y / 2)` and save a lot of computation. Also, using `long` as a return value is safer.

Comment: But there exist efficiency and common sense. That's why i thought no one goona final 32767^32767 with recursion.

Comment: @Problematic: Please. What do you think 256 * 128 is? I don't see those as particularly large numbers. Use an unsigned long long, pretty please with sugar on top. And who said a linear recursion was the best idea? There are other ways than a simple linear recursion to solve this, e.g. exponentation by squaring.

Comment: @Bathsheba It's 37488. But thing is I'm just returning the return it's tail recursion so no need to worry if it's in range of int.

Comment: You are aware that the behaviour of signed integral type overflow is undefined?

Comment: But as you said to use unsigned it's even more disastrous.

Comment: What makes you say that? At least the wraparound behaviour is defined.

Comment: What if someone provide (-2,2) as input and i define variable as unsgined. Can you predict ?

Comment: Or (2, -2) then the fun really does begin... For your case you can always put the sign back in but I'm clutching at straws here.

Comment: That's why I didn't use unsigned but you asked me to use unsgined type.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using recursion:

```
double power(double x, double n, double product = 1) {
    if (n <= 0) return product;
    product *= x;
    return power(x, n - 1, product);
}

int main()
{
    cout << power(10, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming integral base and exponent, why not just do loop unrolling then. Assuming sizeof(int) = 4 bytes = 32 bits.

```
long long power (int base, int exponent)
 {
  long long result = 1;
  long long powOf2 = base;

  if (exponent%2)
    result *= powOf2;
  exponent >>= 1;
  powOf2 *= powOf2;

  if (exponent%2)
    result *= powOf2;
  exponent >>= 1;
  powOf2 *= powOf2;

  (copy paste 30 more times)

  return result;
 }
```

If sizeof(int) = 8, copy paste 62 more times instead of 30.