# Different output with different optimization levels in GCC

Tags: gcc, g++, c++17, sfml

I am working on a rewrite of a raytracer that I developed for university last semester and I am running into the following problem:
When I compile and run my code in Debug the output is as expected

[image: expected result]

But when I enable higher optimization levels e.g. "-O2" something completely different is the result:

[image: actual result]

And I am not sure why this happens. I tracked it down to the sphere intersection code

```
//#pragma GCC push_options
//#pragma GCC optimize("O0")

Intersection Sphere::intersect(const Ray& ray, const float previous) const
{
    const auto oc = ray.origin - center_;
    const auto lhv = -dot(ray.direction, oc);
    const auto discriminant = lhv * lhv - (oc.lensqr() - radius_ * radius_);

    if (discriminant < 0.0F)
    {
        return Intersection::failure();
    }
    float distance;
    const auto rhv = std::sqrt(discriminant);
    const auto r = std::minmax(lhv + rhv, lhv - rhv);
    if (r.first <= 0.0F)
    {
        if (r.second <= 0.0F)
        {
            return Intersection::failure();
        }
        distance = r.second;
    }
    else
    {
        distance = r.first;
    }

    const auto hit = ray.getPoint(distance);
    const auto normal = (hit - center_).normalize();

    if (0.0F <= distance && distance < previous - epsilon)
    {
        return {distance, ray, this, normal, hit};
    }
    return Intersection::failure();
}

//#pragma GCC pop_options
```

If I uncomment the pragma in release mode, I get the expected result again. Maybe I have some undefined behaviour in my code that leads to this?

You can also have a look here as a minimal reproducible example is not easily possible. https://github.com/Yamahari/RayTracer/blob/master/rt/solid/Sphere.cpp

(You can also clone the repo and build the project with cmake, you only need SFML as a dependency.

Use -DSFML_INCLUDE_DIR="include_dir" and -DSFML_LIB_DIR="lib_dir" with the sfml library compiled with your desired compiler)

Comment: _Maybe I have some undefined behaviour in my code that leads to this?_  99.44% likely.  Have you tried turning on all compiler warnings?

Comment: Yes, I am using '-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic', and the only warnings I get is unused parameters and a non-standard gcc extension, but the code that uses that extension is not used in the example

Comment: I would use `-O3` and then disable all the disable-able warnings `-fno-blahblah`, then turn them on in batches until you can isolate the particular optimization(s).  Once you have the optimization culprit(s), you may gain insight as to what undefined behavior the code is tripping over.  Although, not all optimizations have an explicit compiler flag to enable/disable.  The provide code snippet is not [mcve].

Comment: Can you step through the suspicious code with a debugger? Once in debug and once in release

Comment: Does `Intersection` have any reference members, or does the constructor make copies of all the parameters it gets?

Comment: Are you using `-ffast-math` in your optimized builds?  That breaks strict conformance if IEEE floating points.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm copies all of them

Comment: @NathanOliver no, I am only passing '-O2', I also tried with '-fno-fast-math', did not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::minmax` returns a pair of references to its arguments. If you call it with prvalues as arguments, the references in this pair will be dangling after the end of the full-expression, which means that the access `r.first` in

```
if (r.first <= 0.0F)
```

will have undefined behavior here.

So store `lhv + rhv` and `lhv - rhv` in variables and call `std::minmax` on them or use

```
std::minmax({lhv + rhv, lhv - rhv})
```

to select the `std::initializer_list` overload, which returns a pair of actual values.

---

As noted by @Jarod42 in the comments, you don't actually need `std::minmax` here. `rhv` is the result of a `std::sqrt` call, so it is always non-negative, making `lhv + rhv` always the bigger (or equal) value.

Comment: @Yamahari Yes, it is not a good design choice. I think `std::minmax` should have another overload that returns by-value if either argument is an rvalue or alternatively the first overload should be SFINAEd if an argument is a rvalue. You might be better of writing such a version yourself, so that this cannot happen again.

Comment: Would `const auto [min, max] = std::minmax(lhv + rhv, lhv - rhv);` fix this? Aren't `min` and `max` immediately unpacking the returned values (which should still be valid, since the execution didn't reach the end of the full-expression which created the temporaries)? Given the fact that `auto` would **not** preserve references, I think it would work by copying the values.

Comment: @Fureeish No, structured bindings only refer into the members of the object they are bound to. No new objects are created for the individual members. So `const auto [min, max]` will materialize a `const std::pair<const T&, const T&>` which lives until the scope ends, and `min` and `max` will refer to this `pairs`'s `first` and `second` members, which are (thereafter dangling) references.

Comment: Dang it, unfortunate. Thank you, though!

Comment: Yeah this is one of those really unfortunate places where you even use `auto` and you think you're fine and... you're not.

Comment: As `rhv` is result of `sqrt` so "positive", you might directly do `const auto [min, max] = std::pair(lhv - rhv, lhv + rhv);`

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't even notice that the `std::minmax` call wasn't needed. I have added that to my answer.