# How can I find math operations that would be optimized by `-ffast-math`?

Tags: c++, math, compiler-optimization, static-analysis, fast-math

The `-ffast-math` C++ compiler option allows the compiler to perform more math optimizations that may slightly change behavior. For example, `x * 10 / 10` should cancel but due to the possibility of overflow it would slightly change behavior, and `x / 10.0 / 10.0` may have different rounding errors than `x / 100.0`.

However, as many resources have noted, including many questions here on StackOverflow, the `-ffast-math` C++ compiler option can result in strange behavior across platforms. Instead, the recommended approach is to manually add parentheses around the operations you want the compiler to optimize.

Is there a way to identify these parts of the codebase? Some kind of static analysis tool that can find all lines of code that would be different if `-ffast-math` were enabled, so that the programmer can manually adjust those lines of code to be optimized even without `-ffast-math` enabled?

Comment: You seem worried about unsafe math optimizations that may very slightly change the numerical results. But this is only one of the many effects of `-ffast-math`. That great answer lists all effects of the flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135559 . To me, the most dangerous is the wrong handling of NaN and infinity, that may change completely the behavior of the program (and the reason why I didn't enabled it on our code base). And also the removal of `errno` variable would be harmful if you use it.

Comment: @prapin I am only interested in the optimization effects that I can replicate by adjusting my code.