# Why is a simple FP loop not auto-vectorized, and slower than a SIMD intrinsics calculation?

Tags: c++, optimization, x86-64, compiler-optimization, simd

(Why?) does the compiler not use SIMD instructions for a simple loop computing a sum, even when compiling with `-03 and -march=native`?

Consider the following two functions:

```
float sum_simd(const std::vector<float>& vec) {
    __m256 a{0.0};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i += 8) {
        __m256 tmp = _mm256_loadu_ps(&vec[i]);
        a = _mm256_add_ps(tmp, a);
    }
    float res{0.0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        res += a[i];
    }
    return res;
}

float normal_sum(const std::vector<float>& vec) {
    float sum{0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        sum += vec[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The compiler seems to turn the summations into:

```
vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rax + 4*rdx]
```

and

```
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 4]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 8]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 12]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 16]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 20]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 24]
vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rsi + 28]
```

When I run this on my machine, I get a substantial speedup (~factor 10) from the SIMD sum. The same is true on Godbolt. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9Koz4PM4G) for the code.

I compiled the program with GCC 13 and Clang 17 and used the options `-O3 -march=native`.

Why is the function `normal_sum` slower and not fully vectorized? Do I need to specify additional compiler options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the function normal_sum slower and not fully vectorized? Do I need to specify additional compiler options?

Yes. **`-ffast-math`** solves this issue ([see on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vo8x3EzsM)). Here is the main loop with this additional flag:

```
.L10:
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rax]     ;     <---------- vectorized
        add     rax, 32
        cmp     rcx, rax
        jne     .L10
```

However, note that `-ffast-math` is a combination of several more specific flags. Some of them **can be quite dangerous**. For example, `-funsafe-math-optimizations` and `-ffinite-math-only` can break existing codes using infinities or reduce their precision. In fact, some codes like a [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) requires the compiler not to assume floating-point operations are associative (which `-ffast-math` does).
For more information about this, please read the post [What does gcc's ffast-math actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do).

The main reason why the code is not automatically vectorized without `-ffast-math` is simply because floating-point operations like a sum is **not associative** (i.e. `(a+b)+c != a+(b+c)`). Because of that, the compiler cannot reorder the long chain of floating-point additions. Note that there is a flag specifically meant to change this behaviour (`-fassociative-math`), but it is often not sufficient to auto-vectorize the code ([this is the case here](https://godbolt.org/z/qh3vjcnKd)). One need to use a combination of flags (subset of `-ffast-math`) to enable the auto-vectorization regarding the target compiler (and possibly its version).

Non-fast-math is also why the horizontal sum loop in your manually-vectorized version is so inefficient, shuffling to extract each element 1 at a time, instead of shuffling to narrow in half for SIMD sums.  See *[Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction)*

---

A simple architecture-independent way to vectorize the code is to use **OpenMP**. To do that, you need to add the line `#pragma omp simd reduction (+:sum)` before the loop and the compilation flag `-fopenmp-simd` (or the full `-fopenmp` which would also let it try to auto-parallelize). [See on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmm27IE%2Bi0eBFH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8cAbpVExNe3D2bbDF2XgORzceBYLGCBGIwQAdAgfvdflRaKgmAR9qgEowALLKAD6Ch8EDQDAm%2BzOIBAHwcJFBKLRBB%2BZli%2Bxp80OAHYrPd9nz9gz0RSfCZuRpRQARI48h68/lbBLEJjAFhMTEsBIU8HofbETDoLxVAT7CDWEBEljzX78gUkE0pABemHxGLwrwl%2B3Fmws%2BzdoLZlVhjswECt3sOlmseA5oplNptFojVk2HppJgArBY8Bmpd7rfLOVKkXK%2BXqCCsGMKWNLfpLa8XZXdBRiLYTtSSBOTKdTPnTjs3maz2Vy4/z8fiWGZ06ymLGNLDxYWayXbcR7QR0FTgy7fe7PdLd/6aUG8E7Qwe/ZGU/sABwx7n5%2BP7ceT6f7AgavcT1%2BxfGopgGviCQKKaLJppm2bphKYajk%2BapHB635Tr%2BAHoEBIEfgkpD7EwMGPlyRZ3Daza6pgChzgudZ5iu/BrhA26unuXo%2Bn6xy3ge1hRvesHxnqChJghOEZlmObLkRBaETaZYVqR5HUQ8S73Bwiy0Jw6a8H4HBaKQqCcG4nGWBSyyrC8Ww8KQBCaMpiwANYgJsmywg5zkua58SqRwkgaVZOmcLwCggBoFlWYscCwEgaAanQ0TkJQkUJNFMTAFwmxmHwdAENEAUQBEPkRMEdQAJ6cOZ%2BXMMQhUAPIRNonwlbwkVsIIlUMLQxVabwWARF4wBuGItABdwnWYKqRjiB1pD4HqVQfIN2mYKolReJl9XkIIbQ%2BRcERKhVHhYD50LgvViwosqCgAGp4JgADulXYpp5n8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOoE26C0BhGCgBk2FtAWQIsWIdINAC0lWbPs0OqqsCIpqoN6xNDsSSNDbzw9D/D3Rq0MpCw6C8KgHzEDCWBg6GrTtGkLgMO4nhNP4zO9EUJTZMkqQCKMzSJLzHSc/0pT0581STALegVEanSTKLszixM3Qy%2BMivTFzcyLAoxlrBIKlqd5E26Rw%2BxoxjWP7MAyDIPsKWwmYJq4IQdpmfMvCWR18y2fZjmuYHznuZwXmkJp2lm/5gXBT7pBhYgKCoFF9BkBQHYpwMuyGMlnIaC0NC0JlxDZblE1lUVq0VxV1W1Q4q2NYwBAtW1PldT1fW0ANq1YKNwDjdpU2S7NPkLUtK1DWtmUedpW07YVe3rNph0sMdfAGMAF1Xbd92rU9wiiOI73719ag%2BboaUA8YwP6JctMQwkUOcLDeNI8gKMSpbmPY7jCME4wRMSZkx0pTamZF4C6zaJLZwEBXDq1IIELWYsea5DSPAnIfMGBK25uMKB8sugjFZmMCW%2BDNaFGQRrNWRDBaq3qNgnWSwVgGy4EbDg6lw4%2BTNhbdG399jZyMA7TkC5YRcBdvgL4EZNgsK9iFP2DknJB0DvoUOJtI5%2BVsDHb2WhfbKI4GYVR5N1FaOsqQSmKRnCSCAA).

Clang happens to accept it even without the `reduction` clause, but this isn't guaranteed to work or even produce correct results.  You do actually need to match the `+` in the reduction clause with the operation you do in the source: for integer at least, if you use `reduction (*:sum)` or `(&:sum)`, it knows that a starting `sum = 0` times or AND anything equal 0, so [optimizes to just return 0](https://godbolt.org/z/rEr98EvM5) even though the loop body is `sum += vec[i]`.

Anyway, for floating-point, `omp simd reduction` tells the compiler that it's ok to pretend operations on that variable are associative, for just this loop.  The rest of your program can still have strict FP semantics.

Comment: You must specify `reduction(+:sum)` on the `omp simd` pragma for correctness (and then it gets vectorized by GCC).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Y993YTajP - unfortunately even with OpenMP used correctly (telling the compiler about the reduction), GCC still doesn't unroll with multiple accumulators. (`-O3 -fopenmp-simd -funroll-all-loops` will unroll, but each `vaddps` reads an output from the previous one, completely defeating [the latency-hiding purpose of unrolling for FP reductions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction).) And GCC's openMP cleanup is still scalar, not shuffles.

Comment: Clang does a much better job on the OpenMP loop, using 4 dep chains in 4 registers.  (But using an indexed addressing-mode that will un-laminate on Intel :/).  And its cleanup of the final 8-element vector is still 7x `vaddss` scalar ops with shuffles to extract each element separately, vs. memory for GCC which is probably better.  IDK why compilers are so bad at this; they know how to shuffle mostly non-terribly to reduce a vector in half until 1 element with `-ffast-math` when auto-vectorizing. ([Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764))

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the edit. Yeah for GCC this is a frequent issue and quite boring (especially since GCC is quite frequently used to compile HPC codes and this sometimes reduce a bit the performance of applications). I did not know `-funroll-all-loops` could fix it, but it seems quite aggressive since it impacts all the code and can certainly make it much bigger (and so possibly slower sometimes). There is an `simdlen` OpenMP clause which should be useful in such a case but it looks like GCC ignore it (like most SIMD directive/clause AFAIK).

Comment: @PeterCordes On Clang, using the clause `simdlen(16)` should produce a pretty code assembly code (maybe even optimal on some machines assuming the vector is huge). For the clean-up, I expect a masked load to be pretty fast, but AFAIK security vulnerability patches can make such instruction significantly slower now :/ (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.07940.pdf) for example).

Comment: @PeterCordes What do you mean by *"using an indexed addressing-mode that will un-laminate on Intel"*? uiCA reports 2 uops per `vaddps` which seems good to me (one for the load and one for the computation -- no additional cost). Did I miss something?

Comment: [Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26046634) . 
 `vaddps ymm0, ymm0, [rdi]` is 1 uop for the front-end (fused-domain), `vaddps ymm0, ymm0, [rdi + rdx*4]` is 2 on SnB-family, unlike `addps xmm0, [rdi+rdx*4]` (on Haswell and later, or Nehalem and earlier).  Both are of course 2 unfused-domain uops for the back-end execution ports.  Fusion saves front-end bandwidth and space in the ROB, letting out-of-order exec see farther so it helps even when the front-end isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting! I use not to pay much attention on micro-instruction fusing, but it is a good example where it matters since it is a apparently bottleneck on Skylake (not on IceLake). If my understanding is correct, one can expect a 25% speed-up once fixed. It looks like compilers do not care much about that. Sometimes they even miss basic macro-fusion too (even on simple examples). Thank you for the information.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Yeah, I should probably report some missed-optimization bugs since even when clang unrolls, it often doesn't take advantage of the opportunity to save uops. MSVC even uses pointer subtraction so one addr mode in the loop can be non-indexed, but uses it for a pure load /facepalm. ICL does still un-laminate the same as Skylake according to uiCA, it just has a wider front-end so it's sometimes not the bottleenck. (uiCA gets it right for Skylake so I'm confident Andreas Abel knows about micro-fusion and unlamination and hopefully tested this when validating its predictions for ICL)

Comment: GCC until way too recently I think didn't include tuning for macro-fusion in `-mtune=generic`, long after both Intel and AMD CPUs did it.  IIRC I mentioned that in a bug report once (I forget if I filed one specifically about that, or as an aside in a different one, and a GCC dev replied that they weren't confident how much worse it would be for CPUs *without* macro-fusion to schedule instructions that way.  OoO exec makes it mostly fine :/).  But I think GCC does try to group for macro-fusion by default now, even if you don't use `-march=haswell` or whatever like you had to in older versions.