# How can vector computations in Julia be significantly faster than c++?

Tags: c++, performance, julia

I made a test on my computer to compare computational efficiencies of Julia and C++. You can see the simple codes used for these tests:

Julia

```
L  = Int64(1e7) 
a = rand(L)
b = rand(L)
t = time_ns()
res = sum((a .* b))
println(res, " ", (time_ns() - t) / 1e9)
```

output:

```
2.500265152364894e6 0.017575333
```

C++

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
int L = 1e7;
double *a = new double[L], *b = new double[L];
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    a[i] = (rand() % 10000) / 10000.0;
    b[i] = (rand() % 10000) / 10000.0;
}
auto t =std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    res += a[i] * b[i];
}
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - t);
std::cout << res << " " << (elapsed.count() * 1e-9) << "\n";
```

output:

```
2.49865e+06 0.0421434
```

Isn't it surprising that Julia is more than twice as fast as C++?

Comment: Code regarding performance should mention all necessary details like compiler used(with version), **optimization** used(if any), etc

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock` is the better option for timing things. `high_resolution_clock` is mostly a lie. Also, there's a memory leak.

Comment: c++ is notoriously slow to compile, also because the optimizers are so good, thats why by default you get no optimizaition at all but quick compile times. As you didnt mention it, I guess you did not turn on optimizations and unoptimized c++ can be arbitrarily slow

Comment: Julia is specialized for operations like that. It's using extremely optimized routines (written in C or C++) for these things.

Comment: Besides that, make sure that the C++ code is built with optimizations enabled. And do all tests at least a few thousand times to get a decent average.

Comment: My output when passing `-O3`: `2.49997e+06 0.0138035`. So, I *will not* reproduce. https://godbolt.org/z/v6aPbzYs3

Comment: `2.50027e+06 0.00944265` here https://godbolt.org/z/9dcq9zKex

Comment: This is a very simple code. Therefore, I assumed that C++ compiler would automatically optimize it. How can I optimize a C++ code. I am using Xcode.

Comment: Especially with C++, that idiom about assuming holds true.

Comment: In your build settings there should be options (checkboxes) to enable optimizations. Or else you need to manually add `-O3` as a compiler command-line argument (there should be an input field for that).

Comment: And a note about optimizations, it tend to create code in such a way that it's hard to impossible to debug. Therefore the compiler will do the least effort possible so the code can be easily debugged. You need to explicitly tell the compiler to use more effort to optimize.

Comment: Your `Julia` example is using a 64-bit integer.  The C++ `int` type is range based; modern day it could be 32-bits or 64-bits.  Usually the word size of the processor.

Comment: You don't need to use `new` in C++.  You could prefix the declaration with `static`, which places the array in a location with usually more space than local area.

Comment: Your initialization loop is suffering from *cache misses*.  The processor may have to unload `a[i]` before it can load in `b[i]`, *especially when `a[i]` is far from `b]i]`.  The Julia initializes all of `a[]` before `b[]`, thus having better performance with the data cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I set the optimization level to `-Ofast` in the build settings. Now the output is `2.49983e+06 0.00839383`.

Comment: Be *very*  careful with `-Ofast`. It enables some optimizations that break the rules of standard C++ (to achieve extra speed) and they can sometimes lead to subtly incorrect results. Prefer `-O3` or `-O2` that stick to the rules and don't suddenly surprise you with tricky bugs in the compiled program.

Comment: To be more precise `-Ofast` enable `-ffast-math`. See [What does gcc's ffast-math actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do) for more information about the later. That being said, it should make the `res += ...` part faster (vectorized). See [Why is a simple FP loop not auto-vectorized, and slower than a SIMD intrinsics calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77758934/why-is-a-simple-fp-loop-not-auto-vectorized-and-slower-than-a-simd-intrinsics-c/77759090#77759090) for more information.