# Optimizing a Frequently Called dot product Function in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, dot-product

I have a function in C++ that calculates the delta energy for a given lattice and interaction matrix. The function works even for non-symmetric interaction matrices. Here is the code:

```cpp
double delta_energy(const std::vector<int>& lattice, const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& J, int k) {
    int S_k = lattice[k];
    double interaction_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lattice.size(); ++i) {
        interaction_sum += J[i][k] * lattice[i] + J[k][i] * lattice[i];
    }
    interaction_sum -= 2 * J[k][k] * lattice[k];
    double delta_E = -2 * S_k * interaction_sum;
    return delta_E;
}
```

The code is fairly simple and basically calculates a dot product using a for loop. I've profiled my code. This function is called many times in my code and has become the bottleneck. I tried to optimize this function using OpenMP for parallel computing, but it didn't work (it takes even longer, even for large matrices, which doesn't make sense for me). I'm looking for alternative ways to optimize this function, or at least get a sense on how to make this function faster.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` is not a great way to store a matrix.  While each row is contiguous, there is no guarantee that rows will be contiguous with each other.  Instead wrap a 1d vector in a class and pretend that is a 2d vector using maths.

Comment: I'm seconding Nathan's recommendation here. A layered container will *never* perform well because the inner elements can be scattered all over the heap. You *must* flatten this into a single *contiguous* region of memory.

Comment: I got 16% increase in speed. Thanks. Do you recommend anything else? @NathanOliver

Comment: OpenMP might help now that you are using a 1d vector.  Depends on how big these vectors and matrices are.

Comment: [doug has a really simple example class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301) that does what Nathan  describes beautifully. You'd barely have to change any of your code to use it.

Comment: Low-hanging fruit: Make sure you've turned on (or turned up) the optimizer when compiling. Amazing how many people don't and work their asses off hand-optimizing their programs to get the similar-or-worse benefits. There aren't many people who can out-optimize a compiler these days.

Comment: How large are those vectors/matrices? If they are large, the bottleneck may be the bus to the RAM. In that case, switching to `float` may improve performance. What effects this has depends on the sizes, but also on the CPU, the compiler/stdlib and perhaps even your code if it contains lots of `double` <-> `float` conversions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt basically they can be in the order of thousands, or tens of thousands. (Size of lattice)

Comment: Your bottlenecks are branching and data cache reloads (a.k.a. cache misses).  Loop unrolling will help reduce the branching issues.   You may want to change your algorithm to work on smaller pieces that fit inside the data cache.  Another suggestion is to load registers (constant temporary variables) in a block, then process them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main bottleneck of this code should be **`J[i][k]`** by a large margin. Indeed, the loop iterator is `i` so **memory access are non-contiguous** and the stride between accesses is huge. Even worse, **the stride is variable** due to the `vector<vector<double>>` which is inefficient as mentioned in @NathanOliver in the comments. Flattening the matrix helps to reduce the memory access overhead so the CPU can better prefetch data but the code is still very inefficient due to the large stride. Because of that it should be clearly **memory-bound**. Thus, the key is to optimize memory accesses.

TO understand how bad the situation is, one need to know that the CPU load a chunk of typically 64 bytes when one item is fetched from the main memory. This chunk is called a cache-line. On top of that, if the contiguous dimension of `J` is a power of two, typically like the size of the CPU cache, there will be a lot of **conflict misses** in the CPU cache. Thus, the cache will be poorly used and the latency of each fetch will be high. Due to the large-strided accesses, the CPU needs to **reload 8 times the same cache-lines** from the main memory assuming `J` is too large to fit in the cache (which is likely the case since `lattice.size()` is said to be "in the order of thousands, or tens of thousands" and the matrix shape is expected to be squared due to the transposed access). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818324/how-does-the-cpu-cache-affect-the-performance-of-a-c-program/71911346#71911346) is a related post showing how conflict misses can cause a huge **cache-trashing** overhead.

One solution is to follow the [Data Oriented Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design), that is, to **compute multiple `k` items in `delta_energy`** and return multiple results (by storing the resulting value in a fixed-size static array). This solution enable to **reuse cache-lines multiple times before they are evicted**. It is similar to the one proposed by @ThomasMatthews in the comments. It is not clear how you call `delta_energy`, but if you call it in a loop with independent iterations, then it is better to compute the two loops in the same function and use tiling as proposed. In fact, one can also use [Lebesgue curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) to speed things up with a cache oblivious algorithm (though this is not trivial to implement).

An alternative solution is to **pre-compute the transposed matrix of `J`** so `J[i][k]` accesses can be contiguous. This solution is sub-optimal as it requires more data to be read from memory and it consume more memory too. However, it is certainly simpler to implement. The transposition can be done efficiently using a `BLAS` library or any **optimized matrix library** (e.g. Eigen). You can then write:

```
// JT is the transposed contiguous matrix of J
interaction_sum += JT[k][i] * lattice[i] + J[k][i] * lattice[i];
```

Now the accesses are contiguous thanks to the transposition, the code can be auto-vectorized by optimizing compilers assuming fast-math flags are enabled (`-ffast-math` on Clang/GCC). Otherwise, a compiler will not vectorize efficiently the code because **FP-math is not associative**. Be aware that [`-ffast-math` (or equivalent flags) can be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do) though. OpenMP SIMD directives can help to vectorize the code without the possibly-dangerous flag though is is not always efficient on all compiler yet. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77758934/why-is-a-simple-fp-loop-not-auto-vectorized-and-slower-than-a-simd-intrinsics-c/77759090#77759090) for more information about this.

Moreover, you can **factorize the expression** `interaction_sum += J[i][k] * lattice[i] + J[k][i] * lattice[i];` to `interaction_sum += (JT[k][i] * + J[k][i]) * lattice[i];`.

Last but not least, you can also pre-compute an array `lattice_double` which is the `double` version of `lattice` so to avoid doing many `int` to `double` casts. However, it increase the size of the array which may not fit in the L1 cache any-more regarding its actual size though the `L2` is generally fast too and I expect `J` and `JT` loads to be the bottleneck anyway.

The resulting code will certainly be *still memory-bound* but the amount of data loaded from the RAM should be much smaller and contiguous memory accesses will certainly cause the code to be bound by the memory throughput (with no visible memory latency overhead).

Answer (score 0):

There might be several issues that affect your performance:

1. Memory fragmentation leading to cache misses - try to avoid vector of vectors and using a single vector for the matrix storage.
2. Math operations on multiple values can be optimized to be executed simultaneously by using SIMD (if your target CPU supports it). I would recommend starting from making sure that you compile the executable with maximum optimizations and with flags that would allow your CPU to use special architecture-dependant instructions. That would be **-march=native** on GNU compilers and something like **/arch:AVX2** on MSVC. It should already give you some additional performance boost. Here is an example of simple **-O3** vs **-O3 -march=native** disassembly with GCC compiler on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Td563939b.
3. If it still won't satisfy your requirements, you could try manually writing code with SIMD instructions. Keep in mind that SIMD instructions are platform-dependant.
4. Another performance boost can be achieved by using **float** instead of **double**. Of course, if lesser precision would be satisfactory for your needs.

Some links:
[Microsoft SIMD article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/parallel/openmp/openmp-simd?view=msvc-170)
[Wiki SIMD article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data)

Comment: The proposed solutions should *not* make things significantly faster. SIMD/auto-vectorization is nearly irrelevant here because of the `J[i][k]` non-contiguous access which should be the bottleneck. Thus, enabling AVX2 will not make things faster (even gather instruction will be slow because of cache trashing and also because they do scalar load on all mainstream processor anyway). Manually writing a SIMD code with SIMD instruction will make the code barely readable for nearly no benefits. Using floats will not solve the big bottleneck of poor memory accesses.

Comment: @JérômeRichard yeah, I agree, memory access is the issue here rather than computation speed. Your solution is better