# How to flush denormal numbers to zero for apple silicon?

Tags: c++, arm, apple-silicon, denormal-numbers

I'm looking for an equivalent to x86/64's FTZ/DAZ instructions found in <immintrin.h>, but for M1/M2/M3. Also, is it safe to assume that "apple silicon" equals ARM?

I am in the process of porting a realtime audio plugin (VST3/CLAP) from x64 Windows to MacOS on apple silicon hardware. At least on x64, it is important for realtime audio code, that denormal numbers (also known as subnormal numbers) are treated as zero by the hardware since these very-small-numbers are otherwise handled in software and that causes a real performance hit.

Now, as denormal numbers are part of the IEEE floating point standard, and they are explicitly mentioned over here https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/d/Application-Level-Architecture/Application-Level-Programmers--Model/The-optional-Floating-point-extension/Floating-point-data-types-and-arithmetic?lang=en#BEICCFII, I believe there must be an equivalent to intel's _MM_SET_FLUSH_ZERO_MODE and _MM_SET_DENORMALS_ZERO_MODE macros. Of course, I might be mistaken, or maybe the hardware flushes to zero by default (it's not really clear to me from the ARM document), in which case, I'd like to know that, too.

Comment: Specifically what are you wanting to do? Perhaps that’s a clue of what you really need to do

Comment: @DanielA.White I think they are looking for the Apple Silicon equivalent of FTZ/DAZ.

Comment: I want denormal numbers to be flushed to zero. They are very CPU expensive. It's for a realtime audio plugin.

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Application-Level-Programmers--Model/Floating-point-data-types-and-arithmetic/Flush-to-zero?lang=en

Comment: *Also, is it safe to assume that "apple silicon" equals ARM?*  **Yes**.  All Apple Silicon is ARM.  (Not all ARM is Apple Silicon.)

Comment: @Eljay thanks. I thought as much but I wasn't entirely sure as wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) mentions "mainly using the ARM arch".

Comment: Looks like there’s a specific register you set

Comment: @DanielA.White jup, looks like it. I just found this https://github.com/DLTcollab/sse2neon which does exactly that. I'm hoping to leave the question open a little bit longer to see if anyone comes up with apple or ARM provided headers that do the same thing. I don't really want to include an extra dependency in my project just to toggle a floating point register bit.

Comment: Apple silicon is **NOT** ARM.  It is a clean room implementation of ARM.  ARM puts it through a testing suite for conformance, but it is not a formal equivalence.  Some companies directly buy the ARM hard cells.  Apple only bought a license to make a CPU that behaves the same as an ARM chip.  It is quite possible that it can deviate from equivalent ARM hard cells.  Is this what you want (first google hit on 'arm neon denormalization'). https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Instruction-Set-Architecture/Flush-to-zero-mode

Comment: The default is flush to zero and compilers must insert code to handle denorms, if they can not prove the code would keep the values in range.  To avoid the compiler inserting such code, you can use `-ffast-math` or other flags that are a sub-set. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do

Comment: @artless noise judging by the sse2neon source code (see above) and this https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/System-Level-Architecture/System-Control-Registers-in-a-VMSA-implementation/VMSA-System-control-registers-descriptions--in-register-order/FPSCR--Floating-point-Status-and-Control-Register--VMSA?lang=en it seems what i want to do is toggle bit 24 of the FPSCR. It looks like that handles both denormals-are-zero and flush-to-zero.

Comment: @artless noise regarding your comment "FTZ is default", I can only find this statement "The value of this bit only controls Floating-point arithmetic. Advanced SIMD arithmetic always uses the Flush-to-zero setting, regardless of the value of the FZ bit." over here: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/System-Level-Architecture/System-Control-Registers-in-a-VMSA-implementation/VMSA-System-control-registers-descriptions--in-register-order/FPSCR--Floating-point-Status-and-Control-Register--VMSA?lang=en. Any definitive statement that FTZ is default "always"?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family#Architectural_licence in regard to Apple and ARM. It is conformant HDL to some ARM test-suite or compliance tests.  It is wrong to say it is ARM silicon.  There will be deviations, especially if you use the device in non-spec modes.

Comment: This is the correct documentation for the ARMv8 FPSCR (which wikipedia says Apple M3 is complaint with). https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-12/AArch64-Registers/FPCR--Floating-point-Control-Register  For FPUv3, FTZ was a default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257307/discussion-between-sjoerd-van-kreel-and-artless-noise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `<fenv.h>` and use:

```c
int r = fesetenv(FE_DFL_DISABLE_DENORMS_ENV);
// check r == 0
```

From `man fegetenv`:

```
The fesetenv() function attempts to establish the floating-point environment
represented by the object pointed to by envp.  This object shall have been
set by a call to fegetenv() or feholdexcept(), or be equal to a floating-point
environment macro defined in <fenv.h>.
```

And from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/fenv.h` (gated behind an `__arm64__` ifdef check):

```c
/*  FE_DFL_DISABLE_DENORMS_ENV
 
    A pointer to a fenv_t object with the default floating-point state modified
    to set the FZ (flush to zero) bit in the FPCR.  When using this environment
    denormals encountered by floating-point calculations will be treated as
    zero.  Denormal results of floating-point operations will also be treated
    as zero.  This calculation mode is not IEEE-754 compliant, but it may
    prevent lengthy stalls that occur in code that encounters denormals.  It is
    suggested that you do not use this mode unless you have established that
    denormals are the source of measurable performance problems.
 
    Note that the math library, and other system libraries, are not guaranteed
    to do the right thing if called in this mode.  Edge cases may be incorrect.
    Use at your own risk.                                                     */
extern const fenv_t _FE_DFL_DISABLE_DENORMS_ENV;
#define FE_DFL_DISABLE_DENORMS_ENV &_FE_DFL_DISABLE_DENORMS_ENV
```

Test code:

```c
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef volatile union
{
    float f;
    uint32_t u;
} num_debug_t;

int main(void)
{
    num_debug_t n = { .u = 0x00800001 };
    printf("Hex value: 0x%08x\n", n.u);
    printf("Float value: %e\n", n.f);
    printf("===== Normalised =====\n");
    num_debug_t d = { .f = n.f / 2.0f };
    printf("Division result hex: 0x%08x\n", d.u);
    printf("Division result float: %e\n", d.f);
    int r = fesetenv(FE_DFL_DISABLE_DENORMS_ENV);
    if(r != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fesetenv returned %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("===== Denormalised =====\n");
    d.f = n.f / 2.0f;
    printf("Division result hex: 0x%08x\n", d.u);
    printf("Division result float: %e\n", d.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hex value: 0x00800001
Float value: 1.175494e-38
===== Normalised =====
Division result hex: 0x00400000
Division result float: 5.877472e-39
===== Denormalised =====
Division result hex: 0x00000000
Division result float: 0.000000e+00
```

Under the hood, this simply sets bit 24 (FZ) in the `FPCR` system register.