# OpenMP parallel for loop and std::vector reduction

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have  the following simplified code fragment that produces slightly different results at each execution. Results also differ from the serial version. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with it ?

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(vec_float_plus : std::vector<float> : \
                              std::transform(omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), std::plus<float>())) \
                    initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)

vector<float> vec0;
vec0.resize(M);
std::fill (vec0.begin(),vec0.end(),0);

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(vec_float_plus : vec0) 

for (int i0=0;i0<M;i0++)
{
    for (int j0=0;j0<M;j0++)
    {
        vec0[j0]+=A[i0]*B[i0]*C[i0]; // A, B, C are vectors of size M
    } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is because [floating point addition is not associative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371890/9385966). Not enough details to tell, we would need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Quantify *slightly different results*.

Comment: @High Performance Mark difference is around 0.1 %

Comment: @Goran Flegar I will make it as soon as possible

Comment: What compiler are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50222760/2542702

Comment: @Z boson g++ 7.3.0

Comment: Adding float operations are very prone to underflow approximations. Done the wrong way you can easily show that sum 1/n is a finite sum when we all now that it converges to infinity… maybe your data is very heterogeneous (1,0 to 1,0e-15) and the way you add data is important hence the difference between serial and parallel