# Losing precision when converting radian to degrees

Tags: c++

I have radian value of double data type `x`.

`x =  0.423438990337458964763328594926861114799976348876953125;`

When converting this value to degrees then back to radians, I expect the computer to give me the same value of `x` without losing precision.

I am using the `qRadiansToDegrees` method in `qt` and it seems perfect, but I still lose precision when trying to access the value of `x`.

If this is fixable, can somebody please tell me how to prevent this from occurring? If it isn't, is there another way to represent `doubles` so that they don't lose precision after converting?

Comment: *Why* would you assume such a conversion would not lose precision?

Comment: A 64 bit floating point type only has like 16 decimal places of percision.

Comment: There's no way your number actually has that amount of precision (why do you need that much anyway?).

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10077).

Comment: Could you post the exact code you used and how you conclude you get back the wrong number?

Answer (score 7):

In computing, a [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can hold 53 significant digits in binary which translates to `math.log(2**53, 10)` ~= **15 significant digits** in the decimal system we use.

Thus you cannot expect `0.423438990337458964763328594926861114799976348876953125`, which has 54 significant digits, to be represented accurately.

If you really need this amount of precision there are separate libraries for handling high-precision numbers. However these are slower and likely not necessary.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How many of those branches call such arbitrary precision numbers "double"s? Everyone knows exactly what this answer is saying, using clear and commonplace terminology. I don't think it's in any way ambiguous or hard to understand.

Comment: Well, *that* particular value [can](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TzhsKkSqACgLV716) be represented exactly (and it's not an accident, I assume).

Comment: @Bob__  My bad -- it seems these particular 54 digits can be represented exactly, but only 15 of those are guaranteed actual precision, the other 39 are "pseudo-precision". Those can get lost during arithmetic.

Comment: Although funnily enough I just tried it in Python and get back the same result (`x == x * (pi / 360) * (360 / pi)`, also see `'{0:.60f}'.format(x)`). Not sure what is going on with OP.

Comment: @xjcl I wouldn't expect `(pi / 360) * (360 / pi)` to produce any actual code; it trivially cancels out.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  Well, same result if you divide it into two statements `y = x * (pi / 360); x == y * (360 / pi)`

Comment: @xjcl Yes, same story. Compilers don't just translate each line of code one at a time. They "understand" your algorithm and produce a real program matching those semantics, in efficient code targeted at your computer's platform. You're just writing an abstraction.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  But I did it an interpreted (REPL) session

Comment: @xjcl That can be different then

Answer (score 0):

> x = 0.423438990337458964763328594926861114799976348876953125

That particular value happens to be exactly representable as an IEEE-754 `double`<sup>(1)</sup>. We can find out its closest neighbourgs with a little [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/-EnmTA).

```
0.4234389903374589092521773636690340936183929443359375
0.423438990337458964763328594926861114799976348876953125
0.42343899033745902027447982618468813598155975341796875
```

Note that a value like `0.423438990337459` it's *not* exactly representable by a `double` and will be internally approximated by one of those<sup>(2)</sup>. Also note that their relative "distance" is around 10<sup>-16</sup>.

In general, it's always possible to obtain the exact base 10 representation (with a maybe big, but finite number of decimal digits) of a floating point value with radix 2. The inverse is in general not possible (you'll need an inifinite number of bits to represent 0.1). I suspect the OP obtained this value by inspecting a particular `double` using a debugger.

> When converting this value to degrees then back to radians, I expect the computer to give me the same value of x without losing precision.

I don't know how `qRadiansToDegrees` is implemented in Qt, nor what architecture the OP are using,  but when I tried a possible implementation of this round trip I was *lucky* (see e.g. the first result [here](https://godbolt.org/z/CG3GX8)).

In general you should lower your expectations, I'm afraid, considering that a [floating point multiplication is not even associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative).

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/cZ49zb) I tried to test the percentage of failures with random angles. It's around 25% in that testing environment.

---

<sup>1) The C++ Standard doesn't mandate the IEEE-754 standard for representing floating point values. The point of this answer, though, is that any fixed-sized representation can't possibly guarantee what the OP is expecting.</sup>

<sup>2) Some architectures may provide a wider precision (like 80-bits) for registers, so that intermediate results and calculations in general can be more accurate. This is just an example.</sup>