# How to write fast c++ lazy evaluation code in Fastor or Xtensor?

Tags: c++, optimization, lazy-evaluation, expression-templates, xtensor

I am a newbie in c++, and heard that libraries like *eigen*, *blaze*, *Fastor* and *Xtensor* with lazy-evaluation and simd are fast for vectorized operation.

I measured the time collapsed in some doing basic numeric operation by the following function:

(Fastor)

```
using namespace Fastor;

template<typename T, size_t num>
T func2(Tensor<T,num> &u) {

    Tensor<T,num> z;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z = u * u;
        z /= exp(u+u);
        z *= 1.;
        z *= sin(u) * cos(z);
    }
    return z(last);
}
```

(Xtensor)

```
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func2(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<num>> &u) {

    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<num>> z;

    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z = u * u;
        z /= xt::exp(u+u);
        z *= 1.;
        z *= xt::sin(u) * xt::cos(z);
    }
    return z(0);
}
```

compilation flag :

(Fastor)

```
-std=c++14 -O3 -march=native -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG -mllvm -inline-threshold=10000000 -ffp-contract=fast  -mfma -I/Path/to/Fastor -DFASTOR_NO_ALIAS -DFASTOR_DISPATCH_DIV_TO_MUL_EXPR
```

(Xtensor)

```
 -std=c++14 -O3 -march=native -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG -mllvm -inline-threshold=10000000 -ffp-contract=fast  -mfma -I/Path/to/xsimd/include/ -I/Path/to/xtl/include/ -I/Path/to/xtensor/include/ -I/Path/to/xtensor-blas/include/ -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -lblas -llapack -DHAVE_CBLAS=1
```

compiler : `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)`

processor : 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5

for comparison, I also measured the function written in python which optimized by `numba.vectorize`

```
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func(x):
    for k in range(100):
        z = x * x
        z /= np.exp(x + x)
        z *= 1.0
        z *= np.sin(x) * np.cos(x)
    return z
```

the result (in unit of usec) shows that

```
---------------------------------------
num     |  Fastor  |  Xtensor | numba
---------------------------------------
100     |  286     |  201     | 13
1000    |  2789    |  1202    | 65
10000   |  29288   |  20468   | 658
100000  |  328033  |  165263  | 3166
---------------------------------------
```

Am I doing anything wrong? How could Fastor and Xtensor be 50x slower.

How could I make the use of expression template and lazy-evaluation by using `auto` keyword?

Thanks for your help!

---

---

@Jérôme Richard
Thanks for your help!

It's interesting how Fastor and Xtensor are not able to ignore the redundant for-loop. Anyway, I made a fairer comparison of each numeric operation.

The factor 2 from SIMD also makes sense.

(Fastor)

```
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_exp(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += exp( u );
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_sin(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += sin( u );
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_cos(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += cos( u );
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_add(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += u;
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_mul(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z *= u;
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_div(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z /= u;
    }
    return z(0);
}
```

(Xtensor)

```
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_exp(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += xt::exp( u );
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_sin(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += xt::sin( u );
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_cos(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += xt::sin( u );
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_add(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z += u;
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_mul(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z *= u;
    }
    return z(0);
}
template<typename T, size_t nn>
T func_div(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z /= u;
    }
    return z(0);
}
```

(Numba)

```
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_exp(u):
    z = u
    for k in range(100):
        z += exp(u)
    return z
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_sin(u):
    z = u
    for k in range(100):
        z += sin(u)
    return z
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_cos(u):
    z = u
    for k in range(100):
        z += cos(u)
    return z
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_add(u):
    z = u
    for k in range(100):
        z += u
    return z
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_mul(u):
    z = u
    for k in range(100):
        z *= u
    return z
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_div(u):
    z = u
    for k in range(100):
        z *= u
    return z
```

the result shows

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
unit [1E-6 sec] |          exp              |         sin               |           cos             |         add           |           mul         |          div          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
                |   F     |   X     |   N   |   F     |   X     |   N   |   F     |   X     |   N   |   F   |   X   |   N   |   F   |   X   |   N   |   F   |   X   |   N   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
n=100           | 135/135 | 38/38   | 10    | 162/162 | 65/32   | 9     | 111/110 | 34/58   | 9     | 0.07  | 0.06  | 6.2   | 0.06  | 0.05  | 9.6   | 0.06  | 0.05  | 9.6   |
n=1000          | 850/858 | 501/399 | 110   | 1004/961| 522/491 | 94    | 917/1021| 486/450 | 92    | 20    | 43    | 57    | 22    | 40    | 91    | 279   | 275   | 91    |
n=10000         | 8113    | 4160    | 830   | 10670   | 4052    | 888   | 10094   | 3436    | 1063  | 411   | 890   | 645   | 396   | 922   | 1011  | 2493  | 2735  | 914   |
n=100000        | 84032   | 46173   | 8743  | 104808  | 48203   | 8745  | 102868  | 53948   | 8958  | 6138  | 18803 | 5672  | 6039  | 13851 | 9204  | 23404 | 33485 | 9149  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

formats like `135/135` indicates the result `without/with` the `-ffast-math`.

It turns out that

1. Fastor/Xtensor performs really bad in `exp`, `sin`, `cos`, which was surprising.
2. Fastor/Xtensor scales worse than Numba in `+=`, `*=`, `/=`.

Is this the nature of Fastor/Xtensor?

---

I modified the expression to

```
template<typename T, size_t num>
auto func_exp2(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z=u + 100. * exp(u);;
    return z;
}

template<typename T, size_t nn>
auto func_exp2(xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> &u) {
    xt::xtensor_fixed<T, xt::xshape<nn>> z=u + 100.*xt::exp(u);
    return z;
}

@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_exp2(u):
    z = u + 100 * exp(u)
    return z
```

and it gives

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
unit [1E-6 sec] |     Fastor    |     Xtensor   |      Numba    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
n=100           |     0.100     |     0.066     |       1.8     |
n=1000          |     0.073     |     0.057     |       3.6     |
n=10000         |     0.086     |     0.089     |      26.7     |
n=100000        |     0.056     |     0.065     |     275.7     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's happening?

1. why Fastor/Xtensor is not able to express the for-loop to a naive `100*exp(u)` by lazy-evaluation?
2. why Fastor/Xtensor gets faster as tensor size increases?

Comment: The performance of the `exp`,  `sin` and `cos` functions can be very different from one implementation to another. The same thing also apply for the accuracy of these functions. Vectorizing those function while following strict IEEE-754 compliance is very hard. Thus most implementation do not enable the SIMD implementation without the `-fast-math` compiler option. I advise you to add it if possible and to benchmark each of the trigonometric function separately. I also advise you to check you get the same result with the same input. What is the input data used for the benchmark?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks! I replied to your comment by adding a new answer.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the Numpy implementation is much faster is that it does **not compute the same thing** as the two others.

Indeed, the python version does not read `z` in the expression `np.sin(x) * np.cos(x)`. As a result, the Numba JIT is clever enough to **execute the loop only once** justifying a factor of 100 between Fastor and Numba. You can check that by replacing `range(100)` by `range(10000000000)` and observing the same timings.

Finally, XTensor is faster than Fastor in this benchmark as it seems to [use its own fast **SIMD implementation** of exp/sin/cos](https://godbolt.org/z/1fKhb9) while Fastor seems to [use a scalar implementation from libm](https://godbolt.org/z/bT316v) justifying the factor of 2 between XTensor and Fastor.

---

**Answer to the update:**

> Fastor/Xtensor performs really bad in exp, sin, cos, which was surprising.

No. We cannot conclude that from the benchmark.
What **you are comparing is the ability of compilers to optimize your code**. In this case, Numba is better than plain C++ compilers as it deals with a *high-level SIMD-aware* code while C++ compilers have to deals with a huge *low-level template-based code* coming from the Fastor/Xtensor libraries.
Theoretically, I think that it should be possible for a C++ compiler to apply the same kind of high-level optimization than Numba, but it is just harder. Moreover, note that Numpy tends to create/allocate temporary arrays while Fastor/Xtensor should not.

In practice, Numba is faster because `u` is a constant and so is `exp(u)`, `sin(u)` and `cos(u)`. Thus, **Numba precompute the expression** (computed only once) and still perform the sum in the loop. The following code give the same timing:

```py
@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64)'],nopython=True)
def func_exp(u):
    z = u
    tmp = exp(u)
    for k in range(100):
        z += tmp
    return z
```

I guess the C++ implementations do not perform this optimization due to the lazy evaluation. It may a good idea to report this optimization issue on the two github projects.

Moreover, note that `u + u + ... + u` is not strictly equal to `100 * u` as [the floating-point addition is not associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857). While `-ffast-math` help to overcome this problem, compilers may still fail to perform this kind of optimizations due to conflicting optimization passes. For example, too many iterations can prevent loop unrolling which then can prevent the factorization of the expression.

I strongly advise you to perform **more realistic benchmarks**.

> Fastor/Xtensor scales worse than Numba in +=, *=, /=.

Numba may replace the division by a constant with a multiplication in this case (ie. `1/u` may be **precomputed**). Beside that, note that Fastor and Numba are relatively close each other.

> why Fastor/Xtensor is not able to express the for-loop to a naive 100*exp(u) by lazy-evaluation?

I think **lazy-evaluation does not means expressions are automatically factorized**/optimized. It rather means that the result should be computed only when it is required. However, expression factorization could be a good feature to add in future Fastor/Xtensor releases (apparently missing yet).

> why Fastor/Xtensor gets faster as tensor size increases?

I think they are just as fast, not faster (timing variations are probably noise). Thus, I guess the expressions are not actually computed. It is likely due to the **lazy-evaluation** since `z` is never read. Try with `return z(0);` rather than `return z;` (the former forces the expression to be evaluated).

Comment: See my answer. OP has mixed runtime and compile-time constructs. They are re-evaluating the expression templates at every assignment. These libraries can reduce most of these operations symbolically, but OP is evaluating the expression templates eagerly since C++ is strongly-typed. Python is dynamically-typed, so lazy evaluation can persist over loops and through reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how lazy evaluation works. C++ is a strongly-typed language, and Python is not. When you perform an operation that produces an expression template, it produces a new type.

This code:

```
using namespace Fastor;

template<typename T, size_t num>
T func2(Tensor<T,num> &u) {

    Tensor<T,num> z;
    for (auto k=0; k<100; ++k){
        z = u * u;
        z /= exp(u+u);
        z *= 1.;
        z *= sin(u) * cos(z);
    }
    return z(last);
}
```

Does not produce what you think it does. `z = u * u` produces an expression template representing `u * u`, immediately invokes it and assigns it to `z`, because z is of type Tensor<T, num>. For the expression templates to carry over the loop, the type of z would have to change with each iteration! This is possible in Python since python is a dynamically-typed language. Fastor and xtensor assume you are attempting to evaluate the expression at each step, thereby ruining any chances they have at performing reductions (which many libraries such as Blaze, Eigen, Fastor, xtensor, etc do. Fastor's documentation even states it will attempt to automatically reduce the expression using einsum notation and reductions where possible. Its implementation has a relatively sophisticated cost model for how simple the library really is).

To do this in C++, you need to unroll the loop and not assign to z until you're ready to evaluate. You can do this using `std::make_index_sequence`:

```
template<std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
constexpr auto unroll(std::index_sequence<Is...>, T&& expr) noexcept -> decltype(auto)
{
    return ((Is, expr), ...);
}

template<std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
constexpr auto unroll_add(std::index_sequence<Is...>, T&& expr) noexcept -> decltype(auto)
{
    return ((Is, expr) + ...);
}


template<typename T, size_t num>
T func2(Tensor<T,num> &u) {

    Tensor<T,num> z = unroll(std::make_index_sequence<100>{},
        u * u
        / exp(u+u)
        * 1.
        * sin(u) * cos(z)
    );
    return z(last);
}

template<typename T, size_t num>
T func_exp(Tensor<T,num> &u) {
    Tensor<T,num> z = u + unroll_add(std::make_index_sequence<100>{},
        exp( u );
    );
    return z(0);
}
```

With expression templates, you can perform multi-step operations like this without immediately invoking the expression:

```
auto&& a = u + u; // add<T&, T&>
auto&& b = a * u; // mul<add<T&, T&>, T&>
Tensor c = b;.  // Tensor is evaluated here
```

Comment: Interesting explanation for the lazy-evaluation. It makes sense. That being said. For one iteration, this method does not help Fastor to produce a particularly more optimized code based on the resulting assembly. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fPGjPWffe). For more iterations, the template-based unrolling [causes the loop to be optimized](https://godbolt.org/z/PsPb7bxvY) with Fastor. With Xtensor, the generated code is so huge that it is very hard to see the difference.

Comment: There are few important points to mentions: the template unrolling code requires the number of iterations to be a compile-time constant. One can partially unroll the loop (predefined tile size) though it makes the code more complex. The current code apparently requires C++17. It is also harder to read (though this is common for fast codes) and slower to compile.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I agree with pretty much everything you said.  Explicit unrolling can cause cache and stack problems as well, so partial unrolling is often a better option.  The real issue is the scenario where the expression templates need to propagate the loop bounds, as it's impossible to create a lazy view over for loop iterations (since the expression template produces a type that must be known at compile-time).  This is one of the considerations that users of expression template libraries will always need to consider, unfortunately.