# Make Python group operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-optimization, numba

```py
def f1(x):
    for i in range(1, 100):
        x *= 2
        x /= 3.14159
        x *= i**.25
    return x

def f2(x):
    for i in range(1, 100):
        x *= 2 / 3.14159 * i**.25
    return x
```

Both functions compute exactly the same, but `f1` takes 3x longer to do so, even with `@numba.njit`. Can Python be made to recognize the equivalence in compilation, just like it optimizes in other ways seen with [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html) by e.g. throwing out unused assignments?

Note, I'm aware floating point arithmetic cares about order, so the two functions may output slightly differently, but if anything *more* separate edits to array values are *less* accurate, so it'd be a 2-in-1 optimization.

---

```
x = np.random.randn(10000, 1000)
%timeit f1(x.copy())        # 2.68 s ± 50.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit f2(x.copy())        # 894 ms ± 36.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit njit(f1)(x.copy())  # 2.59 s ± 65.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit njit(f2)(x.copy())  # 901 ms ± 41.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: The two functions are essentially identical, but one involves three vector operations and the second involves just one.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm aware of the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numba.jit` is probably the best optimization you will get for the moment for this kind of function. You may also want to try `pypy` and do some benchmark comparisons.

Although, I want to point out why the two functions are *not* equivalent and so you should not expect `f1` to be reduced to `f2`.

The order of operation goes as follows for `f1`:

```
x1 = (x * 2)            # First binary operation
x2 = (x1 / 3.14159      # Second binary operation
x3 = x2 * (i ** 0.25)   # Third and fourth binary operation

# Order: Multiplication, division, exponent, multiplication
```

Which is not the same as for `f2`:

```
x *= ((2 / 3.14159) * (i ** 0.25))
#  ^     ^          ^     ^
#  |     |          |     |
#  4     1          3     2

# Order: Division, exponent, multiplication, multiplication
```

Since [floating-point arithmetic is not associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative), those may not yield the same result. For that reason, it would be wrong for a compiler or interpreter to do the optimization you expected unless it is meant to optimize floating-point precision.

I am not aware of a Python tool which is meant to do this specific kind of optimization.

Comment: I'm aware regarding associativity, but if anything _more_ modifications to array values are _less_ accurate, so it'd be a two-in-one optimization.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I am not sure to understand what you mean by modifications to array values being less accurate

Comment: For example, roundoff error accrues over repeated e.g. addition, whereas adding all at once involves only one roundoff. Typical issue in machine learning.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I see. Then back to you problem: if you benchmarked f2 as being faster, why not just use it instead of f1? This is not the kind of optimization I think you should expect a Python compiler to do today... hopefully in the future we will find some ways.

Comment: Readability problems; long line plus in scientific computing context, introduces illogical flow of ideas. Basically like an ugly vectorization vs intuitive but slow for-loop. Nothing one can't compensate with enough inline comments, but would be better if the compiler took care of it instead.

Comment: [Quick example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XYN7.png), but it can get much worse

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I see. The problem is even ahrder in that case because psihfn could dynamically be assigned another function. This makes static analysis terribly complexe in Python.

Comment: Right, not the best example

Answer (score 0):

Probably can't do it with the jit. I have tried fastmath and nogil kwarg specified in the api: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/jit-compilation.html

`f0` is still slightly slower than `f1` after getting rid of overflow or denormal number.
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zinS4.png)

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numba as nb


def f0(x):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        x *= 3.000001
        x /= 3
    return x


def f1(x):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        x *= 3.000001 / 3
    return x


def timing(f, **kwarg):
    x = np.ones(1000, dtype=np.float32)
    times = []
    n_iter = list(range(100, 1000, 100))
    f2 = nb.njit(f, **kwarg)
    for i in n_iter:
        print(i)
        s = timer()
        for j in range(i):
            f2(x)
        e = timer()
        times.append(e - s)
    print(x)
    m, b = np.polyfit(n_iter, times, 1)
    return times, m, b, n_iter


def main():
    results = []
    for fastmath in [True, False]:
        for i, f in enumerate([f0, f1]):
            kwarg = {
                "fastmath": fastmath,
                "nogil": True
            }
            r1, m, b, n_iter = timing(f, **kwarg)
            label = "f%d with %s" % (i, kwarg)
            plt.plot(n_iter, r1, label=label)
            results.append((m, b, label))
    for m, b, kwarg in results:
        print(m * 1e5, b, kwarg)
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.xlabel("n iterations")
    plt.ylabel("timing")
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're not using a large array.