# Why is convolution not always commutative/associative?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, computer-vision

Convolution is supposed to be commutative and associative, so ((f * g) * h)(x) = (f * (g * h))(x) = ((f * h) * g)(x) etc. I've found that this isn't the case with some implementations. Here is the test I did:

```py
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy import ndimage


def convolve_1(image, kernel):
    return cv2.filter2D(image, cv2.CV_64FC1, cv2.flip(kernel, -1), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)


def convolve_2(image, kernel):
    return signal.convolve2d(image, kernel, mode='full', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)


def convolve_3(image, kernel):
    return signal.fftconvolve(image, kernel, mode='full')


def convolve_4(image, kernel):
    return signal.oaconvolve(image, kernel, mode='full')


def convolve_5(image, kernel):
    return ndimage.convolve(image, kernel, mode='constant', cval=0)


CONVOLUTION_FUNCTIONS = {
    'cv2.filter2D': convolve_1,
    'scipy.signal.convolve2d': convolve_2,
    'scipy.signal.fftconvolve': convolve_3,
    'scipy.signal.oaconvolve': convolve_4,
    'scipy.ndimage.convolve': convolve_5,
}


def main():
    image = cv2.imread('bird.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.float64)
    kernel_1 = np.array([[0, -1, 0],
                         [-1, 5, -1],
                         [0, -1, 0]], dtype=np.float64)
    kernel_2 = np.array([[ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
                         [ 0, -1, -2,  0,  0],
                         [-1, -2, 16, -2, -1],
                         [ 0, -1, -2, -1,  0],
                         [ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0]], dtype=np.float64)

    for function_name, convolve in CONVOLUTION_FUNCTIONS.items():
        print(function_name)
        start = time.perf_counter()
        
        # these results should all be the same
        result_1 = convolve(image, kernel_1)
        result_1 = convolve(result_1, kernel_2)

        result_2 = convolve(image, kernel_2)
        result_2 = convolve(result_2, kernel_1)

        result_3 = convolve(image, convolve(kernel_2, kernel_1))

        print('error 1:', np.mean(abs(result_1 - result_2)))
        print('error 2:', np.mean(abs(result_1 - result_3)))
        print('error 3:', np.mean(abs(result_2 - result_3)))

        print('time taken:', time.perf_counter() - start)
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Here's the image I used.](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/news/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/STanager-Shapiro-ML.jpg?page=Browseby%20Shape)
Here's the output:

```
cv2.filter2D
error 1: 0.8387194444444445
error 2: 290.7564638888889
error 3: 291.58391666666665
time taken: 0.022129999999999983

scipy.signal.convolve2d
error 1: 0.0
error 2: 0.0
error 3: 0.0
time taken: 0.19091079999999994

scipy.signal.fftconvolve
error 1: 5.110803021852462e-13
error 2: 9.780014690145642e-13
error 3: 9.461453672609482e-13
time taken: 0.15763480000000007

scipy.signal.oaconvolve
error 1: 5.656074741440057e-13
error 2: 1.0786530017634777e-12
error 3: 1.1119329649131375e-12
time taken: 0.2334368

scipy.ndimage.convolve
error 1: 0.8387194444444445
error 2: 290.7564638888889
error 3: 291.58391666666665
time taken: 0.040781100000000015
```

It looks like the more accurate functions are slower.

I converted to float64 in case it was a precision error, but that didn't help.

I would like to know why the errors are so large. I would also like to know if there is an implementation (preferably in opencv) that is both accurate and fast, or if this is just an inherent limitation of convolution functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you really think floating point arithmetic errors can account for such high errors, considering that I am using float64?

Comment: It's possible: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: Most likely the problem is the boundary effect. Functions could also be clipping the output on purpose, I suggest you look at the results to verify they do what you think they do. Finally, `cv2.filter2D` is not a convolution.

Comment: The convlutions listsed use different methods to calculate convolution, it has nothing to do communtavity or associativity. Look at the references in the relavent documetation & you'll see for example that `signal.fftconvolve` is calculated in a different manner to `signal.oaconvolve`