# How can I optimize this simple for loop for matrix multiplication

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization, matrix-multiplication

Is there any way to optimize this simple 'for' loop code?

I need to have the fastest execution time.

```
typedef struct
{
  float real;
  float img;
} my_complex;

my_complex* Q = (my_complex*)malloc(8 * 8 * 1960 * sizeof(my_complex));

float sq = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 1960; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
      sq += Q[i * 8 * 8 + k * 8 + j].real * Q[i * 8 * 8 + k * 8 + j].real
          + Q[i * 8 * 8 + k * 8 + j].img * Q[i * 8 * 8 + k * 8 + j].img;
    }
```

Comment: `i * 8 * 8 + k * 8 + j` is calculated 4 times. But it is likely optimized by the compiler.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1960 * 8 * 8; i++) sq += Q[i].real * Q[i].real + Q[i].img + Q[i].img;`.  Many fewer loops; many fewer complex index calculations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You mean less loops in the code, right? Same number of iteration though.

Comment: This is not a matrix multiplication, BTW. It is merely calculating the sum of square of magnitudes of the matrix elements.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I mean one loop instead of three loops. Yes, the total number of operations in terms of multiplication and addition of floating-point numbers is the same — but there is far less computation in the indexes.  Indeed, you could go so far as to use `my_complex *vp = Q; for (int i = 0; i < 1960 * 8 * 8; i++, vp++) sq += vp->real * vp->real + vp->img * vp->img;` which avoids the subscripting altogether. (I observe that the array initialization is not shown — I am assuming that the code does exist so that there isn't undefined behaviour. And if it were my code, I'd use `imag`, not `img`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Given the relative positions of the `j` and `k` loops and the indexing calculation in the posted code, it should also be much more cache friendly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, mainstream compilers are able to **automatically unroll the loops** (assuming optimizations are enabled) so *index calculation is clearly not an issue*. Here is for example the generated Clang assembly code (see on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ybc3cPzhq)):

```
compute:                                # @compute
        add     rdi, 452
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        xor     eax, eax
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rcx, -8
.LBB0_2:                                #   Parent Loop BB0_1 Depth=1
        movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 388] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 384] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm1, xmm1
        addss   xmm1, xmm2
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 324] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 320] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm0, xmm0
        addss   xmm0, xmm2
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 260] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 256] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm1, xmm1
        addss   xmm1, xmm2
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 196] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 192] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm0, xmm0
        addss   xmm0, xmm2
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 132] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 128] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm1, xmm1
        addss   xmm1, xmm2
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 68] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 64] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm0, xmm0
        addss   xmm0, xmm2
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx - 4] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]   # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm1, xmm1
        addss   xmm1, xmm2
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 60] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 64] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm2, xmm2
        mulss   xmm0, xmm0
        addss   xmm0, xmm2
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        inc     rcx
        jne     .LBB0_2
        add     rax, 1
        add     rdi, 512
        cmp     rax, 1960
        jne     .LBB0_1
        ret
```

Modern x86-64 processors can execute many instructions in *parallel* in an *out-of-order* way and they can *pipeline* them efficiently, but there is a catch: they cannot execute *dependent instructions* in parallel. In fact, neither the compiler nor the processor can reorder/optimize the chain of additions in `sq` because **floating point operations are not associative** (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative) for more information). As a result, the accumulation is done serially. You can enable compiler optimizations (like `-ffast-math` for GCC/Clang) so to address this issue (but `-ffast-math` can be unsafe if the code contains special values like NaN or if it rely on the associativity). Alternatively, you can *unroll the loop yourself* using **multiple accumulators so to break the dependency chain** (which is *latency-bound*).

Additionally, the code is **not vectorized** using SIMD instructions. Indeed, `mulss` and `addss` are scalar instructions. Again, fast-math help to address this issue.

Moreover, compilers cannot generate a code using a **wider SIMD instructions sets** like AVX/AVX-2/AVX-512 on x86-64 processors since they are not supported by all processor (typically old ones). You can use `-mavx`/`-mavx2`/`-mavx512` on GCC/Clang to address this issue though this require the target processor to support it (most 10-years old processors support at least AVX and most recent ones support at least AVX-2). You can also enable the fuse-multiply add instruction set with `-mfma`.

Last but not least, the data structure is not SIMD-friendly so compilers can hardly vectorize it efficiently. It is better to operate on a structure of array rather than on an array of structure here. This problem is known as the **"AoS VS SoA"** where AoS means array of structures and SoA means structure of arrays. You can find some information about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA).