# Atomicadd and its non-deterministic nature?

Tags: python, cuda

I first found about [atomic add](https://github.com/xlliu7/TadTR#:%7E:text=the%20non%2Ddeterministic-,AtomicAdd,-operator.%20Please%20refer) here. The performance of the mentioned network is non-deterministic due to that operator.

According to my understanding atomic addition is a type of operation used in parallel computing when multiple threads attempt to update a shared variable concurrently.

When I asked Chatgpt about it's non-deterministic nature, it replied:
'the non-deterministic aspect arises due to the nature of concurrent execution. When multiple threads or processes try to perform atomic addition simultaneously, the order in which these operations are executed or completed might vary. The precise timing and interleaving of these operations can differ between executions, leading to non-deterministic behavior.'

However, I am still confused. If we add 2,3 and 4, the order doesn't matter, the result is always 9. So my main question is, how it is non-deterministic and is there anything we can do to make it deterministic?

Comment: The order of operations does matter for floating point math

Comment: Also relevant: [Is floating-point addition and multiplication associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative)

Comment: By the way, when you talk about "performance" there is an ambiguity. It can refer to the timings or the quality/accuracy of the results. It looks like ChatGPT is confused about that (the answer lack of precision, as it often is). Besice, FP math is precise if you add numbers that can be fully represented without a lack of precision and the sum can too. For example, all integers smaller than <1e6 can be represented precisely in 32-bit IEEE-754 floats. This means adding 2 numbers <5e5 results in a 100% precise number. The error of an addition is 1 ULP.