# Are floating point operations in C associative?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, compiler-optimization

Addition mathematically holds the associative property:

```
(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)
```

In the general case, this property does not hold for floating-point numbers because they represent values in a finite precision.

Is a compiler allowed to make the above substitution when generating machine code from a C program as part of an optimization? Where does it exactly say in the C standard?

Comment: For multiplication at least, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler is not allowed to perform "optimizations", which would result in a different value computed, than the one computed according to abstract machine semantics.

> 5.1.2.3  Program execution
>
> [#1]   The   semantic  descriptions  in  this  International
>          Standard describe the behavior of  an  abstract  machine  in
>          which issues of optimization are irrelevant.
>
> [#3] In the abstract machine, all expressions are  evaluated
>        as  specified  by  the  semantics.
>
> [#13] EXAMPLE 5 Rearrangement for floating-point expressions
>          is often restricted because of limitations in  precision  as
>          well  as  range.   The implementation cannot generally apply
>          the  mathematical  associative   rules   for   addition   or
>          multiplication,   nor  the  distributive  rule,  because  of
>          roundoff  error,  even  in  the  absence  of  overflow   and
>          underflow.

In your example:

```
(a + b) + c
```

or even without the parentheses:

```
a + b + c
```

we have

```
   +
  / \
  +  c
 / \
 a  b
```

and the compiler is required to generate code as if `a` is summed with `b` and the result is summed with `c`.

Comment: Correct theory. The application to take home is: work out what order your operations should happen in (eg if you want to sum small to small, big to big), put in parentheses to satisfy paranoia, and you can stop worrying about the compiler breaking things by reordering.

Comment: Note however, that while operator precedence is well-defined, the order of evaluation of the sub expressions is unspecified. In other words, the program may evaluate this binary tree starting right-to-left, or left-to-right, and it doesn't even have to keep to this order in a consistent manner, nor does it need to document it. So if either a, b or c contained side-effects that affected the result, then the code would be problematic. Say for example that c is a function that modifies a: then we couldn't know the result.

Comment: Just not to forget: "In ISO standards, examples are without exception non-normative". Source: [link](https://www.iso.org/schema/isosts/v1.0/doc/n-asw0.html).

Comment: @Lundin Re: "the order of evaluation of the sub expressions is unspecified": (1) what is the rationale? (2) at what page C11 (or newer) says so?

Comment: @pmor For operators in general, C17 6.5/3. Or for a better text with the same meaning, C99 6.5/3 "the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified."

Answer (score 6):

You can make floating point operations associative with the gcc options:

```
-funsafe-math-optimizations -O2
```

Example:

```
double test (double a, double b, double c) {    
  return (a + b + c) * (a + (b + c));
}
```

This is reduced to:

```
double temp = a + (b + c);
return temp * temp;
```

Similarly, `(a + b + c) - (a + (b + c))` is reduced to zero, ignoring the possibility of `INF` and `NAN`.

If I compile with `-fassociative-math -O2` instead, I get the weird message:

> warning: -fassociative-math disabled; other options take precedence

The `-funsafe-math-optimizations` can improve speed if you don't care about the order of the operands anyway, but it may cause loss of precision if the order of operands is important, and you may lose `NAN` and `INF` results.

Answer (score 4):

**Floating point multiplication in C is not associative.**

```
In C, Floating point multiplication is not associative.
```

**Some evidence is with this C code:**

Pick three random float values.
Check if `a*(b*c)` is ever not equal to `(a*b)*c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(counter++ < 10){
        float a = rand() / 100000;
        float b = rand() / 100000;
        float c = rand() / 100000;

        if (a*(b*c) != (a*b)*c){
            printf("Not equal\n");
        }
    }
    printf("DONE");
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints:

```
Not equal
Not equal
Not equal
Not equal
DONE
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

**Conclusion:**

For my test, three randomly selected floating point multiplication values are associative about 70% of the time.

Comment: The OP asked whether the compiler *assumes* float operations to be associative, when it performs optimizations. He is clearly aware that they actually aren't.

Comment: Yes but its always nice to see an example which confirms the theory.

Comment: This isn't about c, however, it's just telling you something about float point math. Any execution environment that conforms to the IEEE standard will exhibit the same behvior.