# Increment Operator

Tags: java, operators, increment

I missed this question three times on a test. I just can't seem to grasp how to solve this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    public class Test {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             int j = 0;
             int i = ++j + j * 5;

             System.out.println("What is i? " + i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code to se what value i will have?

Comment: The reason it returns 6 is that `++j` is [pre-increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) which increases the value of `j` to 1, and it does it "pre" calculating this line so that when this line is calculated, the value of `j` is already 1. And 1 + 1 * 5 = 6.

Comment: The real lesson: never write this kind of code.

Comment: Thanks alfasin - makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

For:

```
int i = ++j + j * 5;
```

The variable j is per-incremented by 1 with the expression `++j`, that is equal to j+1, changing the value of j to 1. Then following the rules for the order of operations in java, the multiplication is executed `(j * 5)` or `(1 * 5)` at this stage, so currently i = 5. Finally to the product of the multiplication j is added `(j + 5)` or `(1 + 5)` = 6.

You can check this page where this is explain in a simple way:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 1):

As per Java's operator precedence and evaluation order, `i` is equal to `6`. `i` is set equal to `j` which is pre-incremented to `1`, and added to the product of itself and `5`, which is 6.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note here is the difference between `j++` and `++j`. See this: [The difference between ++Var and Var++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175316/the-difference-between-var-and-var)

Keeping this in mind, `++j` will return 1, and change j's value to 1. So the next part, `j*5` is equal to 1*5, which is 5. So overall `++j + j*5` gives you 6.

Answer (score 0):

Java has an [operator precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) rule which means for any mathematical expression in Java which contains operators, postfixes(j++) and prefixes(++j) are evaluated first. There is also [left and right associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589257/what-does-left-to-right-associativity-mean) which is how your statement is parsed. Mathematical operators such as +,-,/,* have left to right associativity. Postfixes and Prefixes have right to left associativity.

Looking at the [Java Grammar File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) one finds that

> The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the
>   variable after the new value is stored

So, ++j is 1 for the current statement.

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the
>   variable before the new value is stored.

So, j++ is 0 for the current statement.

So, (++j) + j * 5 after prefix evaluation becomes (1 + (1 * 5)) = 6.

**[Edit]**

Thus, statement such as j++ + j * 5 will give you 5 as an answer because j becomes 1 after j++(postfix increment) but j++ itself remains 0.

Answer (score 0):

if ++j appears in the statement, the value of j is first incremented and then the statement is executed. But if j++ appears in the statement, first statement is executed and then the value is incremented.

To simply solve execution part, you can ignore ++ sign and simplify it. But don't forget the order of increment and simplification.

Answer (score 0):

According to java operator precedence, `++` operator has higher precedence than `+` and `*` operators. Here's what happens, step by step:

First `++j` happens. Since `j` is 0, `++j` increments `j` to 1.
Now the expression `++j + 5 * j` has become `1 + 5 * 1`.

Now we have two operators, `+` and `*`. Which one is applied first? See the operator precedence chart and  you will find out that `*` has higher precedence than `+` . So first `5 * 1` takes place first. After multiplication the expression looks like `1 + 5`.

Adding `1` to `5`, we get `6`. So....`i = 6` is the result.

If u want to know more about ++ operator, there are some decent videos on youtube.