# What's wrong with my quickCheck type declaration?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I roll my own `elem` function called `elem'`

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' n ys = foldl (\acc p -> if (p == n) then True else False) False ys
```

Seems to work but I want to quickCheck it in GHCi so I `import Test.QuickCheck`

```
verboseCheck (\a -> (\xs ->( (elem' a xs) == (elem a xs)) ) )
```

Without a type declaration on the test function it tests ok, but that's because it's only testing null inputs.

Something is wrong with my type declaration for the test function:

```
verboseCheck (\a->(\xs->((elem' a xs)==(elem a xs))) :: Int->[Int]->Bool)
verboseCheck (\a->(\xs->((elem' a xs)==(elem a xs))) :: Char->[Char]->Bool)
```

Error for first one:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int] -> Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
    • Possible cause: ‘(==)’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs))
      In the expression:
          (\ xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs))) :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
      In the first argument of ‘verboseCheck’, namely
        ‘(\ a
            -> (\ xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs))) ::
                 Int -> [Int] -> Bool)’

<interactive>:258:39: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[()]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘elem'’, namely ‘xs’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘(elem' a xs)’
      In the expression: ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs))

<interactive>:258:54: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[()]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘elem’, namely ‘xs’
      In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘(elem a xs)’
      In the expression: ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs))
```

Comment: Unrelated: `if E then True else False` is usually written `E`.

Comment: which expression would I rewrite with E?

Comment: `if (p == n) then True else False` --> `p == n`.

Comment: ah, I see. thanks for explaining that's a nice simplification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because Haskell thinks that you're constraining the *return type* of the lambda expression `\a->(\xs->((elem' a xs)==(elem a xs)))`. This may be easier to see if you format the expression a bit more idiomatically:

```
\a -> (\xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs)))
```

To the interpreter/compiler, this looks like a lambda expression that returns another expression. All good.

However, when you attempt to annotate it with a type:

```
\a -> (\xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs))) :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
```

Haskell thinks that you're annotating the *return type*, i.e. the right-most part closest associated with the type annotation: `(\xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs)))`.

Surround the entire lambda expression with brackets *before* applying the type:

```
(\a -> (\xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs)))) :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
```

You can now `verboseCheck` that expression:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> verboseCheck ((\a -> (\xs -> ((elem' a xs) == (elem a xs)))) :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool)
Passed:
0
[]

Passed:
0
[]

Passed:
0
[-2,0]

Failed:
1
[2,1,-1]

Passed:
0
[2,1,-1]

Passed:
1
[]

Failed:
1
[1,-1]

Passed:
0
[1,-1]

Passed:
1
[]

Passed:
1
[-1]

Passed:
1
[1]

Passed:
1
[0,-1]

Passed:
1
[1,1]

Failed:
1
[1,0]

Passed:
0
[1,0]

Passed:
1
[]

Passed:
1
[0]

Passed:
1
[1]

Passed:
1
[0,0]

*** Failed! Falsified (after 4 tests and 2 shrinks):
1
[1,0]
```

Most of the brackets, however, are redundant, which is probably what's causing the confusion. You can simplify the expressions to this:

```
verboseCheck ((\a xs -> elem' a xs == elem a xs) :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool)
verboseCheck ((\a xs -> elem' a xs == elem a xs) :: Char -> [Char] -> Bool)
```

Comment: Ah! I cribbed the parens pattern from my lecturer's example of a different function test, adapting it worked for a single arg function but not for double arg functions.
his example was like this:  
`((\n -> (\s ->((decipher n (cipher n s)) == s))) :: Int -> [Char] -> Bool)` which obviously fits your pattern after some reductions. I'm sometimes unsure about where I need parens and where I don't because I don't understand all the precedence order for lambdas and other operators. A relevant tutorial link would be a great  help.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil To be honest, I haven't bothered learning those. I usually just add or remove brackets until things work. Also, if you use *hlint* it'll tell you if you have redundant brackets.

Comment: If you enable `:set -XTypeApplications` (in ghci) or `{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}` in your source file: `verboseCheck (\a xs -> elem' @Int a xs == elem a xs)`. If you want to specify it for `elem` instead you need to write `elem @[] @Int` or `elem @_ @Int`. You can get rid of parentheses with `-XBlockArguments`.

Comment: It is also possible to annotate the arguments of the argument to `verboseCheck`: `\(a :: Int) xs -> ..` or `\a (xs :: [Int]) -> ..`

Comment: Thx @MarkSeemann `hlint` sounds like the go. My lecturer has something in his terminal such that it behaves like a text editor which underlines paren pairs when the cursor is next to them or inside a pair of them, very helpful, I think he's using vim or emacs, I'm just using stock-standard (stack)  GHCi. I found some useful info on SO & elsewhere about fixity and left-associative and right-associative which cleared a lot of it up for me. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589257/what-does-left-to-right-associativity-mean

Comment: Thanks @Iceland_jack, a bit confusing for me to read as a novice but good to know!

Comment: Polymorphic functions (`elem`, `(==)`)  have types as invisible arguments, the `@` syntax lets you pass them explicitly. When you write `head "ABC"` it takes the character type as an invisible argument: `head @Char "ABC"`. It is useful to know, but maybe confusing.