# Error Propagation upon Summing Single-Precision (float) Values

Tags: c, floating-point-precision

I'm learning single precision and would like to understand the error propagation. According to [this nice website](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/), addition is a *dangerous* operation.

So I wrote a small C program to test how quickly the errors add up. I'm not entirely sure if this is a valid way of testing. If it is, I'm unsure how to interpret the result, see below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TYPE float
#define NUM_IT 168600

void increment (TYPE base, const TYPE increment, const unsigned long num_iters) {

  TYPE err;
  unsigned long i;
  const TYPE ref = base + increment * num_iters;

  for (i=0; i < num_iters; i++ ) {
    base += increment; 
  }
  err = (base - ref)/ref;
  printf("%lu\t%9f\t%9f\t%+1.9f\n", i, base, ref, err);

}

int
main()
{
  int j;
  printf("iters\tincVal\trefVal\trelErr\n");

  for (j = 1; j < 20; j++ ) {
    increment(1e-1, 1e-6, (unsigned long) (pow(2, (j-10))* NUM_IT));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The result of executing

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -lm errorPropagation.c && ./a.out  | tee float.dat  | column -t
```

is

```
iters     incVal     refVal     relErr
329       0.100328   0.100329   -0.000005347
658       0.100657   0.100658   -0.000010585
1317      0.101315   0.101317   -0.000021105
2634      0.102630   0.102634   -0.000041596
5268      0.105259   0.105268   -0.000081182
10537     0.110520   0.110537   -0.000154624
21075     0.121041   0.121075   -0.000282393
42150     0.142082   0.142150   -0.000480946
84300     0.184163   0.184300   -0.000741986
168600    0.268600   0.268600   +0.000000222    <-- *
337200    0.439439   0.437200   +0.005120996
674400    0.781117   0.774400   +0.008673230
1348800   1.437150   1.448800   -0.008041115
2697600   2.723466   2.797600   -0.026499098
5395200   5.296098   5.495200   -0.036231972
10790400  10.441361  10.890400  -0.041232508
21580800  25.463778  21.680799  +0.174485177
43161600  32.000000  43.261597  -0.260313928    <-- **
86323200  32.000000  86.423195  -0.629729033
```

If the test is valid

- Why does the error change sign? If `0.1` is represented as e.g. `0.100000001`, shouldn't this accumulate always to the same bias, irrespective of the number of summations?
- What's special about `168600` summations (see `*`)? The error becomes very small. Might be a coincidence.
- Which wall is being hit at `incVal = 32.00` (see `**`, last two lines). I'm still well below the `unsigned long` limit.

Thanks in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's important to know that `0.1` can't be represented exactly, in binary it's has periodically repeating digits. The value would be `0.0001100110011...`. Compare to how 1/3 and 1/7 are represented with decimal digits. It's worth repeating your test with increment `0.25`, which can be represented exactly as `0.01`.

I'll illustrate the errors in decimal, that's what we humans are used to. Let's work with decimal, and assume we can have *4* digits of precision. Those are the things happening here.

- Division: let's calculate 1/11:

  1/11 equals 0.090909..., which is probably rounded to 0.0**9091**. This is, as expected, correct to 4 significant digits (in bold).
- magnitude differences: suppose we calculate 10 + 1/11.

  When adding 1/11 to 10, we have to do more rounding, since 10.09091 are 7 significant digits, and we have only four. We have to round 1/11 to two digits after the point, and the calculated sum is **10.09**. That's a underestimation. Note how only one significant digit of 1/11 is retained. If you add a lot of small values together, this will limit the precision of your final result.
- Now calculate 100 + 1/11. Now we round 1/11 to 0.1 and represent the sum as **100.1**. Now we have a slight overestimation instead of a slight underestimation.

  My guess is the pattern of sign changes in your test are the effect of systematic slight underestimation vs. overestimation depending on the magnitude of `base`.
- What about 1000 + 1/11? Now we can't have any digits after the point, as we have 4 significant digits before the point already. 1/11 is now rounded to 0, and the sum is still **1000**. That's the *wall* you're seeing.
- Another important thing you're not seeing in your test is: what happens if the two values have a different sign. Calculate 1.234 – 1.243: both numbers have 4 significant digits. The result is -0.009. Now the result has only one correct significant digit instead of four.

An answer to a similar question here: [How does floating point error propagate when doing mathematical operations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704731/how-does-floating-point-error-propagate-when-doing-mathematical-operations-in-c?rq=1) . It has a few links to more information.

Comment: The decimal analogy is quite insightful, thanks a lot. Particularly, the explanation of the *wall* makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions...

1 - IEEE float rounds to *even* mantissas. This was done specifically in order to prevent error accumulation from always biasing in one way or the other; if it always rounded down, or rounded up, your errors would be much larger.

2 - Nothing in particular is special about 168600 in and of itself. I haven't mathed it out but it's entirely likely that it ends up making a cleaner value in binary representation (i.e. a rational/non-repeating value). Look at the values in binary, not decimal, and see if that theory holds up.

3 - The limiting factor might be due to the float mantissa being 23 bits long. Once `base` gets to be a certain size, `increment` is so small in comparison to `base` that computing `base + increment` and then rounding the mantissa back down to 23 bits completely erases the change. That is, the difference between `base` and `base + increment` is rounding error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can sort of follow you on points 1. and 2. (I'll have to check your hypothesis), but the explanation of 3. is unclear to me. It's not that `increment * num_iters` has the wrong value. I'm observing that the value of the summation (`base` in the above code) doesn't increase anymore.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying now. The issue is that once `base` gets to be a certain size, `increment` is so small in comparison to `base` that computing `base + increment` and then rounding the mantissa back down to 23 bits completely erases the change. That is, the difference between `base` and `base + increment` is rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

The "wall" you are hitting has nothing to do with the increment value, if it is constant through the addition and you start at zero.  It has to with the `iters`.  2^23 = 8 million, and you are doing 86 million additions.  So once the accumulator is 2^23 bigger than the increment, you hit the wall.

Try running the code with 86323200   iterations, but an increment of 1 or 0.0000152587890625 (or any power of 2). It should have the same relative problem as an increment of 32.

Comment: You are right, using `0.0000152587890625` I'm seeing the same pattern. However, the error increases only when hitting `2^23-2^12` (`2^23-2^13` is still ok, no error). Any explanation for that? Try `increment(1e-1, 0.0000152587890625, (unsigned long) (1   * NUM_IT - pow(2,13)));` and `increment(1e-1, 0.0000152587890625, (unsigned long) (1   * NUM_IT - pow(2,12)));` and `#define NUM_IT 8388608`