# Will converting a string to a double equal the literal double?

Tags: c

For example:

```
assert(atof("1.2") == 1.2);
```

regardless of what float is used?

I understand that the floating point precision isn't exact, but it is precisely inexact so does the rounding to binary produce the exact same double?

Comment: Example: https://ideone.com/SwFcQG

Comment: Yeah, tested several non-trivial numbers and it is surprisingly working. Yet not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the compiler's parsing of such strings is the same as the runtime library (and when you're cross-compiling, you're necessarily using a different implementation).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not guaranteed by the C standard. The semantics of converting a floating-point literal in the source code are specified in C 2011 [draft N1570] 6.4.4.2. This says the recommended, but not required, practice is that the translation-time conversion of floating-point constants should match the execution-time conversion of character strings by library functions, such as `strtod`.

More than that, the standard does not even require that two different literals with the same mathematical value, such as `1.23` and `1.230`, convert to the same value. These examples come from footnote 75 in the standard, which is a footnote to a paragraph stating that all floating-point constants **of the same source form** shall convert to the same value. Thus, `1.23` always converts to the same value wherever it appears in the source, but `1.230` does not necessarily convert to the same value as `1.23` or `123e-2`. Even `123e-2` and `123e-02` may be different.

`atof(p)` is specified in 7.22.1.2 to be equivalent to `strtod(p, (char **) NULL)` except for how they behave with errors. `strtod` is specified in 7.22.1.3. That clause has some recommended practices for accuracy but is silent about matching the translation-time conversion of literals.

Comment: so you'd have to thoroughly vet your compiler before trusting it to do this?

Comment: @PeterHansen you should never trust floating point equality anyway.

Comment: @PeterHansen: Yes, or check its documentation (or source code) or ask its implementor or vendor.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That is bad advice; please do not spread it. Using floating-point properly requires expertise, but it is possible.

Comment: OK, I will say "usually not" instead of "never".

Comment: @EricPostpischil so you should tell beginners to use equality test, or advise them not to? Many questions here about that. The good advice has already been spread without my help, sorry.

Comment: @WeatherVane: On StackOverflow, questions about testing for equality largely arise in toy code, where somebody is inquiring why a computed result is not what they expect. The answer for these people is to explain why the computed result is not what they expect. The test for equality is irrelevant; it was just a tool they were using to explore the behavior and should be disregarded. In real applications, a need to test for equality does not often arise—if you already expect a particular result, you would not be computing it with floating-point.…

Comment: @WeatherVane: … When there is a need to test for equality, the solution always depends on the situation. The oft-repeated bad advice to test with a “tolerance” almost always comes with no guidance about the tolerance and no warning about the need to evaluate the false positives it occurs. (Often the tolerance is given as an absolute value that is inappropriate for **floating** point.) I have written up several answers on testing floating-point results that address these issues.…

Comment: @WeatherVane: … And one thing this advice misses is that the issue is not testing for equality specifically but that floating-point generally should not be used to evaluate discontinuous functions. (Testing for equality maps {(x, y) | x and y are floating-point values } to { 0, 1 }; it is discontinuous in the reals.) Floating-point arithmetic was designed to perform approximate real arithmetic. Any discontinuous function is problematic in floating-point, because rounding errors can move results from one side of a discontinuity to another. When you encounter a need to test for equality,…

Comment: @WeatherVane: … the first question you should ask is whether floating-point is the right tool to use for the problem being solved.

Comment: Just to note that for `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2`, following the C99 rules and Joseph S. Myers' exegesis on a typical compilation platform where `double` is mapped to binary64 and `long double` to the familiar 80-bit extended format, `atof("1.2") == 1.2` is nearly guaranteed to be false in practice, as the precision of the right-hand-side is `long double` and the precision of the left-hand-side, as the result of a function returning `double`, is `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil talking about "toy code" betrays your patronising attitude. I understand what you mean, but the basic advice remains.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is not patronizing; it means code written just to explore the platform, not for a final application. It does not mean the code is not good or suitable for its purpose. In any case, whether it is patronizing or not has nothing to do with correctness.And no, the basic advice does not remain (not good, anyway). Comparing with a tolerance reduces false negatives at the expense of increasing false positives. Without knowing the effect of the false positives in the application, it cannot be known whether comparing with a tolerance is correct.

Comment: I get you, but your argument is Straw Man. I never suggested comparing with a tolerance. Don't use floating point comparisons until you have read Eric Postpischil's thesis. Don't use floating point at all, unless you have MSc at the least.

Comment: @WeatherVane: You are right, I lost the thread, and comparing with a tolerance is a diversion. The issue was using floating-point equality. My points on that stand. Doing the job right is not simple. If it requires study and thought, it requires study and thought. There are numerous textbooks, courses, and papers on using floating-point. Mockery is not a rebuttal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I will strive to one day lose an internet argument as gracefully as you just did.

Comment: @user1717828 Would be better for everyone if people stopped thinking about debates as something to win or loose :)

Comment: Personally I believe an expert such as @EricPostpischil is allowed to patronise anyone. All of his comments here make for good reading and make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This check will inevitably be implementation-dependent, so I've written the following little test script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
  {
  double d1 = 1.2;
  double d2 = atof("1.2");
  char *p;
  double d3 = strtod("1.2", &p);

  printf("d1 = %40.40f\n", d1);
  printf("d2 = %40.40f\n", d2);
  printf("d3 = %40.40f\n", d3);

  if(d1 != d2)
    printf("d1 != d2\n");

  if(d2 != d3)
    printf("d2 != d3\n");
  }
```

In the case of the HP C/C++ compiler, version A.06.25.02, this outputs

```
d1 = 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383800000
d2 = 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383800000
d3 = 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383800000
```

which demonstrates that the conversion (of 1.2, at least) which is performed by the compiler matches the conversions performed by `atof` and `strtod`.

Answer (score -6):

From Military engineering we always account for this issue by placing a tolerance band say +/- 0.000001 around the true float comparison value. This way you know what you are truly comparing and help prevent polluting what the algorithm is designed to do.  One is always working with fuzzy numbers when working with floating point numbers where one can't or should not do a hard comparison on.

Comment: This advice is harmful and will break algorithms working with huge or tiny numbers. Imagine adding 0.000001 when your numbers are 1.234*10^-30 or 1.234*10^30.

Comment: Fist, the original problem was 1.2 not 1.234*10^30,

Comment: The question explicitly states _"regardless of what float is used"_.

Comment: *"One is always working with fuzzy numbers when working with floating point numbers"* - Er, no. There's **nothing"" fuzzy about floating point numbers. They are 100% exact, all the time. Equality comparisons are well defined, all the time.