# cpp unordered_set just use comparator not hash

Tags: c++, set

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

class edge{
    public:
        float a1;
        float a2;

};

struct comp{
    bool operator()(const edge& e1, const edge& e2) const {
        return true;
        return (
            (e1.a1==e2.a1 && e1.a2==e2.a2) ||
            (e1.a1==e2.a2 && e1.a2==e2.a1)
        );
    };
};
struct hash{
    size_t operator()(const edge& e1) const {
        // return std::hash<float>()(e1.a1+e1.a2);
        return std::hash<float>()(e1.a1+e1.a2*2);
    };
};


int main() {
    std::unordered_set<edge,hash,comp> s1;
    s1.insert(edge{1.1,2.2});
    s1.insert(edge{2.2,1.1});
    for( auto& it : s1 ) {
        std::cout << it.a1 << " " << it.a2 << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "s1.size " << s1.size() << "\n";
}
```

I realize that if different element has same hash value, then they are considered equal, but I just want this unordered_set use comparator that I define, just ignore hash?

How to achieve that?

I know i can use set, but using set need to consider order, if a < b is true and b < a is also true, then this element will not be inserted successfully, Sometimes, It is hard to provide order.

If anyone can help, much appreciated

---

edited:
My intention is to let two edges called e1,e2, they are same if `(e1.a1==e2.a1&&e1.a2==e2.a2)`or`(e1.a1==e2.a2 && e1.a2==e2.a1)` as I provided
in struct comp.
but when i test. it seems hash function can change the comparison too. Someone says the way I define hash and comparator result in undefined behaviour.
Is that true? why?
if true, how to solve this? I just want comparator decide which one is satisfied to be inserted in unordered_set without duplicate. And really do not care about hash.

BTW, thanks for some many people replying

Comment: Does `std::unordered_multiset`fit your requirements?

Comment: Ordering is usually not hard if you use `std::tie`.

Comment: Your intention is to have `size() == 1`?

Comment: *"I realize that if different element has same hash value, then they are considered equal"* -not true. The point of unordered set  hash+comparator is to provide constant time hashing and linear subtime (k) comparison. A unordered_set is still a *set* (crazy, right?). The elements are unique. That uniqueness is determined by finding the proper collision bucket in the current hash table via the `hash`, then searching for a matching element in the collision bucket via `compare`. If that isn't the behavior you want, then stop trying to shove a square peg in a round hole; use a different container.

Comment: I believe it's not much faster to compare hashes than to compare a pair of `float`s. And your hash looks kinda weak anyway. So I'd consider using `std::set` instead.

Comment: @Evg yeah, i want size() == 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle `edge.a1` and `edge.a2` interchangeably, you have to implement a hashing function that returns the same value even when they are swapped. I advise against using addition, because [addition may not be commutative for floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446382/4253931), but you could sort them by size and combine the hashes afterwards:

```
struct hash {
  size_t operator()(const edge& e1) const {
    auto h1 = std::hash<float>{}(std::min(e1.a1, e1.a2));
    auto h2 = std::hash<float>{}(std::max(e1.a1, e1.a2));
    return h1 ^ (h2 << 1)
  };
};
```

This only makes sense for pretty large sets of floats, because otherwise the hashing overhead probably exceeds the benefit of using a hashed data structure in the first place.

Old answer for reference:

> Objects with the same hash are **not** considered equal in
>   `unordered_set`. They are just stored in the same bucket. There is a
>   [`KeyEqual` template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for the comparison, which by
>   default uses the `operator==` of your `Key`. So your main problem is,
>   that `comp` should implement `e1 == e2` and not `e1 < e2` (and should
>   probably be called `equal`).
>
> The hash is just used to speed up the search, insertion, and removal
>   of elements.
>
> On another note, you may want to use the hashes of the member
>   variables instead of the values themselves to compute the hash of
>   `edge`:
>
> ```
> struct hash {
>   size_t operator()(const edge& e1) const {
>     auto h1 = std::hash<float>{}(e1.a1);
>     auto h2 = std::hash<float>{}(e1.a2);
>     return h1 ^ (h2 << 1)
>   };
> };
> ```
>
> This way, you won't get the same hash for two edges with swapped
>   coordinates. This way of combining hashes is suggested [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) ([but
>   is not a good way to combine more than two](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/utility/hash)).

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the intention was to have `comp` ignore the order of `a1` and `a2`. And then the problem is that the OP's hash function is not correct.

Comment: @Evg Well if OP implements an equals operation instead of a comparison for `KeyEqual` that solves the problem.

Comment: @eike the intention is to ignore order of a1 and a2 since for edge, it does not matter which one is first

Comment: @Athos Ok, that explains a lot. I completely misunderstood your question. Editing now...

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* have to use the members of `edge` to provide the hash. It is only required that equal values have equal hashes. A "always valid" hash is

```
struct hash{
    size_t operator()(const edge& e1) const {
        return 0;
    };
};
```

But it seems your original attempt is better

```
struct hash{
    size_t operator()(const edge& e1) const {
        return std::hash<float>{}(e1.a1 + e1.a2); // + is commutative
    };
};
```

Comment: That would render every benefit of `unordered_set` nullified. Why not just use `set` then?

Comment: @eike Not every benefit. OP can still use their *KeyEqual* (confusingly called `comp`)

Comment: But his implementation, as it seems, is not supposed to implement an equals operation.

Comment: With your `hash`, `size()` returns 1, with OP's `hash`, `size()` returns 2. Why?

Comment: @Evg OPs `hash` + `comp` gives undefined behaviour

Comment: Different hashes for same values... Got it.

Comment: @Evg because for OPs version of comp: `comp(edge{1.1, 2.2}, edge{2.2, 1.1}) == true`

Comment: @Evg No, the hash for two equal values is always the same, even with OPs implementation.

Comment: @eike, "same" as defined by `comp`.

Comment: @Evg Oh sorry, misunderstood that.

Comment: @Caleth Now that I understand the question (and hence your answer), I have to advise against addition, because that is not commutative for `float`.

Comment: @eike it's commutative, but not associative

Comment: @Caleth According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446382/4253931 it isn't, according to other sources it is. I don't know who to trust on this one. In general IEEE754 float addition is commutative, but I haven't found a quote from the C++ the standard about this.