# `-ftree-vectorize` on Clang fails floating-point comparison tests

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, vectorization, compiler-optimization

I recently tried to add the `-ftree-vectorize` compiler option to the build step of my project. I ran tests after the change, and for some reason when compiling with Clang, one of my end-to-end tests fails because of significant floating point differences. This is quite surprising to me, especially since GCC still works fine.

Digging into the issue a bit, I find that from [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) `-ftree-vectorize` turns on 2 separate flags, `-ftree-loop-vectorize` and `-ftree-slp-vectorize`. Clang in its effort to match GCC of course has the `-ftree-vectorize` flag, and also has the `-ftree-slp-vectorize` flag. I tested Clang with just the `ftree-slp-vectorize` option, and the test passes.

However, it doesn't have the `-ftree-loop-vectorize` option so I can't try it with just that, and judging from [Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#optimization-level) I don't even know if `-ftree-vectorize` turns on 2 flags under the hood like GCC.

I am rather stumped on how vectorization can affect floating-point results. I know that floating point operations aren't associative, so I don't believe Clang would break the as-if rule by vectorizing floating point operations. I'm pretty sure that I didn't switch on unsafe math optimizations either, since my compiler options are just `-g -O2 -ftree-vectorize`.

Worst case here I've struck some implementation behavior/UB, but I wanted to ask here first to people more experienced about if there could be something else I'm missing.

Comment: How are you checking the results?  Given that there is no guarantee that `a + b == a + b` https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446382/3370124 you might be running into simple reordering issues.

Comment: What ISA are you compiling for?  x86-64?  If so, then FLT_EVAL_METHOD==0 and things should be fairly sane, with FP results not depending on optimization level or optimization choices.  One thing that compilers can still do (without `-ffast-math`) is contract `a*b+c` into an FMA, at least within one expression.  (`-ffp-contract=on`, vs. across statements with GCC's default of `-ffp-contract=fast`.  But clang doesn't do that unless you tell it, it's default is `off` or `on` IIRC, but not `fast`.)

Comment: Anyway, your expectation is correct, GCC/clang can't vectorize in ways that would change FP rounding except for FMA, since you didn't use `-ffast-math` or `-fopenmp` with `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:foo)` or something in the source.

Comment: @RichardCritten we have tolerances for floating num, comparing absolute and relative differences

Comment: Perhaps you have a bug somewhere?  Different results with different optimization levels can be due to undefined behaviour.  Compile with `-Wall` and check / fix all the warnings.  If your code is multi-threaded, check with thread sanitizer.  Maybe use `clang -O2 -Wall -fsanitize=undefined`

Comment: @PeterCordes that's what I'm fearing sadly, I was just asking this question in hopes it was a bug of lower hanging fruit

Comment: @RichardCritten: The reason that `a+b == a+b` can be false is that either could be NaN, and `NaN==NaN` is false.  For finite inputs, FP addition is commutative, IIRC even for the sign of `+-0.0`.  Also for infinities I think.  It's also commutative for NaN unless you care about the NaN "payload", but the semantics of `==` mean that's not a valid way to express commutativity.  The question you linked has answers that are technically correct because of the behaviour of `==`, but not very helpful in understanding `+`.

Comment: Is there a minimal example that shows your test and compilation commands?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox the test is really big unfortunately, and no unit tests fail. my compilation optimization options are just `-g -O2 -ftree-vectorize` as noted above, the rest are just warning flags

Comment: `-g -O2 -ftree-vectorize` I can't reproduce on a 68000.  A repro case would be most helpful.